# c++ integer->std::string conversion. Simple function?

Tags: c++, integer, stdstring

Problem: I have an integer; this integer needs to be converted to a stl::string type.

In the past, I've used `stringstream` to do a conversion, and that's just kind of cumbersome. I know the C way is to do a `sprintf`, but I'd much rather do a C++ method that is typesafe(er).

Is there a better way to do this?

Here is the stringstream approach I have used in the past:

```
std::string intToString(int i)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s;
    ss << i;
    s = ss.str();

    return s;
}
```

Of course, this could be rewritten as so:

```
template<class T>
std::string t_to_string(T i)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s;
    ss << i;
    s = ss.str();

    return s;
}
```

However, I have the notion that this is a fairly 'heavy-weight' implementation.

Zan noted that the invocation is pretty nice, however:

```
std::string s = t_to_string(my_integer);
```

At any rate, a nicer way would be... nice.

> #### Related:
>
> [Alternative to itoa() for converting integer to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c)

Comment: In your example t_to_string I fail to see why a template specification is required. A template function can determine its template type from its argument types.

Comment: @Zan: Durp. That's what I get for posting code I didn't compile.

Comment: How about some of the examples from the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx   They are very efficient and somewhat elegant.

Comment: @Beh: That library is considerably heavier-weight than a simple t_to_string(). It actually looks like a very nice library, but I wouldn't want to import the whole thing for just doing a t_to_string().

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Now in c++11 we have

```
#include <string>
string s = std::to_string(123);
```

Link to reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: Very spiffy. Have a link to the standard's page describing the function?

Comment: compiler errors for me -- "std::to_string: ambiguous call to overloaded function"

Comment: I would rephrase that to "*Finally*, we have ...".

Answer (score 28):

Like mentioned earlier, I'd recommend boost lexical_cast. Not only does it have a fairly nice syntax:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
```

it also provides some safety:

```
try{
  std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
}catch(boost::bad_lexical_cast &){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Not really, in the standard.  Some implementations have a nonstandard itoa() function, and you could look up Boost's lexical_cast, but if you stick to the standard it's pretty much a choice between stringstream and sprintf() (snprintf() if you've got it).

Comment: Good thing this has been fixed, see [Schaub's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273908/c-integer-stdstring-conversion-simple-function#8362045)