# c++ convert an integer into a string ubuntu

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Alternative to itoa() for converting integer to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c)
>   [c++ integer->std::string conversion. Simple function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273908/c-integer-stdstring-conversion-simple-function)

how can i convert an integer i=123456789 into a string value? 
I am working in c++/ubuntu. THX

I am working in ubuntu 9.10

Comment: C++ is a language that has a standard. Most of the questions on the core language are not OS related, and even if they are, it is much better to just tag the question than add the information to the title. Also, the specific distribution of linux will not make a difference. It does not make sense to include `ubuntu` in the title and `ubuntu 9.10` in the body. At any rate the exact compiler version would help more: `g++-4.2` (or whatever the compiler in ubuntu 9.10 is by default)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss<<i;
std::string s = ss.str();
```

Comment: stringstream is from what library?

Comment: i have an error: no match for operator << in ss<<i

Comment: @Erik: Thanks..Edited accordingly.

Comment: You need to do `#include <sstream>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use lexical_cast:

```
int i = 123456789;
std::string s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);
int j = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s)
```

Comment: what library should i include?

Comment: #include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

Comment: @linuxx: You need to use boost libaries for this: See here : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm