# C++ sql pass integer to sql string

Tags: c++, sql

I have built a database in MS Access.
There I have a table called Customers which also has a cell called Employee type: integer.
I also built a program in C++ which controls all data.

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
string sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Customers Where Customers.Employee = '" + id + "' ";
```

Id passes through my function correctly and is an integer, so I get an error in compilation saying: "Invalid pointer addition".

If I declare id as a string of course there's no error but there are no results in my form also.  If I declare in database cell Employee as text and build my query like this:

```
string sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Customers.Employee = 128";
```

I get results, but I need that Employee as an integer cause its a foreign key from another table.

So, what should I do with my query to have results passing integer as parameter through variable id, to be ok with the cell Employee from database which is also integer?
Any ideas? I would really appreciate some help here.

---

As I said, if I convert id to string, there are no results in my form since Employee in database is an integer.  So this:

```
std::ostringstream buf;
buf << "SELECT * FROM Customers Where Customers.Employee = '" << id  << "' ";
string str = buf.str();
```

won't do the job or any other conversion.

How can I pass id as an integer in my query?

Answer (score 3):

You could use sprintf, but in C++ you can do:

```
std::ostringstream buf;
buf << "SELECT * FROM Customers Where Customers.Employee = '" << id  << "' ";
string str = buf.str();
```

(untested)

Comment: Stirngstream is the preferred way to go. Most queries are written with sqlstream.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert id to a string, then your first approach should work.

See this question for how to do the conversion:
[Alternative to itoa() for converting integer to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
std::ostringstream buf; buf << "SELECT * FROM Customers Where Customers.Employee = " << id ; string str = buf.str();
```

This should work please try '12'  --- quote should not be placed before and after 12

Answer (score 0):

you can use boost::format with boost::str

```
string = boost::str(boost::format("This is a string with some %s and %d numbers") %"strings" %42);
```

this should be better approach since you will have all the replacement variable in one place at the end.