# Data Type Convert

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Is there any function in C++ which converts all data types (`double`, `int`, `short`, etc) to `string`?

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, the answers to this question provide the usual methods of converting built-in types to strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c

Comment: [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/)

Comment: @Kirill `sprintf` is C. There are better, type-safe alternatives in C++.

Comment: Do you really want to convert types to strings (answered by me) or values of types to string (already answered by others)? Converting types to strings is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/print-variable-type-in-c .

Comment: @Tyler McHenry, Surely there are type-safe alternatives, buf if we are talking about one function... Alternatives are not so lightweight. Anyway this is just a comment for information, I didn't give it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually you'll use the `<<` operator, in conjunction with  (for example) a std::stringstream.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm

Answer (score 3):

If boost is not an option (it should always be, but just in case):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template<class T1, class T2>
T1 lexical_cast(const T2& value)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    T1 retval;

    stream << value;
    stream >> retval;

    return retval;
}

template<class T>
std::string to_str(const T& value)
{
    return lexical_cast<std::string>(value);
}
```

Boost has a similar idea, but the implementation is much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in universal function, but [boost::lexical_cast<>](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) will do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need this conversion? A lot of languages have variant types which auto-convert, and this can lead to wanting that behavior in C++ even though there may be a more canonical way of implementing it.

For example if you're trying to do output, using a (string)stream of some sort is probably the way to go. If you really need to generate and manipulate a string, you can use `boost::lexical_cast` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one I use from my utility library.  This was condensed from other posts here on stackoverflow, I am not claiming this as my own original code.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
string ToString(const T& Value) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << Value;
    string s = ss.str();
    return s;
}
```

also, another handy string formatting utility I use:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdarg.h> /* we need va_list */

// Usage: string myString = FormatString("%s %d", "My Number =", num);
string FormatString(const char *fmt, ...) {

    string retStr;

    if (NULL != fmt) {
        va_list marker = NULL;
        va_start(marker, fmt);
        size_t len = 256 + 1; // hard size set to 256
        vector <char> buffer(len, '\0');
        if (vsnprintf(&buffer[0], buffer.size(), fmt, marker) > 0) {
            retStr = &buffer[0]; // Copy vector contents to the string
        }
        va_end(marker);
    }

    return retStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this use stringstream.
First include the header file as #include .
Then create an object of stringstream and using stream insertion operator (<<) pass the contents you want to convert as string.
Ex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main(){
    std::string name = "Ram";
    float salary = 400.56;
    std::stringstream obj;
    obj << name << " salary: " << salary;
    std::string s = obj.str();
    std::cout << s;
}
```