# Does itoa delete char?

Tags: c++, char, delete-operator, itoa

Why does this give me a memory error?

```
char* aVar= new char;
itoa(2, aVar, 10);
delete aVar;
```

Does `itoa` delete the `aVar`? How to know if a C++ function deletes the pointer, is there a convention about that?

If I do this then error doesn't occur:

```
char* aVar= new char;
delete aVar;
```

Comment: `new` is not an operator in c. I have therefore retagged the question to be C++.

Comment: you're right, I'll change it to c++

Answer (score 4):

`itoa` needs array long enough to hold the whole value plus null character at the end.
In your case, you need to allocate at least 2 chars, otherwise the null character at the end falls on the unallocated memory.

See the [documentation on itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/).

For the pure C, `sprintf` should be a more portable solution:

```
char aVar[2];
sprintf(aVar, "%d", 2);
```

(as `itoa`, according to the documentation, is not universally available).

If you are using C++, the better way of them is to use a stringstream. See this question: [Alternative to itoa() for converting integer to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c) for the discussion.

Comment: `char* aVar= new char[2]; itoa(2, aVar, 10); delete[] aVar;`

Comment: But it's ugly code. You should avoid manual memory management and functions that operate on fixed size strings.

Comment: Or just `char aVar[2]; itoa(2, aVar, 10);`

Comment: `std::stringstream` is C++ only. Given that the question is tagged with C, you should be recommending `sprintf` rather than `std::stringstream`. **EDIT**: But just realized OP is using `new` in code... retagging.

Comment: @Vlad I was just replicating the code pattern used by the OP. Of course you can put the array on the stack.

Comment: @Alexandre: you are right, I just assumed that the OP wanted just to have the string somewhere.