# Converting an int to std::string

Tags: c++, string, int

What is the shortest way, preferably inline-able, to convert an int to a string? Answers using stl and boost will be welcomed.

Comment: Related: [Alternative to itoa() for converting integer to string C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c)

Comment: In C++11 you can use [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) like `std::string s = std::to_string(42)`

Comment: Long live C++11 and to_string! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 474, accepted):

You can use [**std::to_string**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) in C++11

```
int i = 3;
std::string str = std::to_string(i);
```

Comment: std::to_string() does not work in MinGW, if anyone cares.

Comment: @bparker Right, it's been fixed in gcc 4.8.0 I guess. MinGW coming with latest Code::Blocks (13.12) still has gcc 4.7.1.

Answer (score 49):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
const int i = 3;
std::ostringstream s;
s << i;
const std::string i_as_string(s.str());
```

Comment: This is good to also include techniques for pre-C++11.  Can this code also be written as: `std::ostringstream().operator<<(i).str()`?

Answer (score 39):

Well, the well known way (before C++11) to do that is using the stream operator :

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream s;
int i;

s << i;

std::string converted(s.str());
```

Of course, you can generalize it for any type using a template function ^^

```
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
std::string toString(const T& value)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << value;
    return oss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 37):

`boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(yourint)` from `boost/lexical_cast.hpp`

Work's for everything with std::ostream support, but is not as fast as, for example, `itoa`

It even appears to be faster than stringstream or scanf:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

Comment: Boost is your friend, if there wasn't a simple way of doing this in Standard C++... I of course like what `lexical_cast` brings, but feel Boost is pretty much overkill for this kind of tasks...

Comment: Overkill? Based on what? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

Comment: Should consider your audience if they are unable to use Boost

Comment: "Answers using stl and boost will be welcomed." - Audience considered

Answer (score 20):

If you cannot use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) from C++11, you can write it as it is defined on cppreference.com:

> `std::string to_string( int value )`
>   Converts a signed decimal integer to a string with the same content as what `std::sprintf(buf, "%d", value)` would produce for sufficiently large buf.

Implementation

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

std::string to_string( int x ) {
  int length = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%d", x );
  assert( length >= 0 );
  char* buf = new char[length + 1];
  snprintf( buf, length + 1, "%d", x );
  std::string str( buf );
  delete[] buf;
  return str;
}
```

You can do more with it. Just use `"%g"` to convert float or double to string, use `"%x"` to convert int to hex representation, and so on.

Answer (score 15):

Non-standard function, but its implemented on most common compilers:

```
int input = MY_VALUE;
char buffer[100] = {0};
int number_base = 10;
std::string output = itoa(input, buffer, number_base);
```

**Update**

C++11 introduced several [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) overloads (note that it defaults to base-10).

Comment: @DevSolar:  You should elaborate.  The boost example had already been given.  This solution is available on most compilers when boost is not installed (or your requirements prohibit you from using it for whatever reason).  The `ostream` works as well, until you need to save the number-string as something other than a binary, octal, or hex format (e.g. base-32).

Comment: I don't like it when non-standard functions like `itoa()` or `stricmp()` are given as the answer to *anything*.

Comment: Sorry to offend your sensibilities, but I did state it was a non-standard function in the first sentence.  I didn't mention it, but `sprintf` can also accomplish the goal of the OP (though still suffers from the lack of flexibility if anything other than the common base numbers is needed).

Comment: Yes you did state it, and I didn't downvote your answer, even when it itched me to do so. So I think we're even. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The following macro is not quite as compact as a single-use `ostringstream` or `boost::lexical_cast`.

But if you need conversion-to-string repeatedly in your code, this macro is more elegant in use than directly handling stringstreams or explicit casting every time.

It is also *very* versatile, as it converts *everything* supported by `operator<<()`, even in combination.

Definition:

```
#include <sstream>

#define SSTR( x ) dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >( \
            ( std::ostringstream() << std::dec << x ) ).str()
```

**Explanation:**

The `std::dec` is a side-effect-free way to make the anonymous `ostringstream` into a generic `ostream` so `operator<<()` function lookup works correctly for all types. (You get into trouble otherwise if the first argument is a pointer type.)

The `dynamic_cast` returns the type back to `ostringstream` so you can call `str()` on it.

Use:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    std::string s1 = SSTR( i );

    int x = 23;
    std::string s2 = SSTR( "i: " << i << ", x: " << x );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @rubenvb: You tell me how to turn this into a template and I'll update all the C++ projects I've been using this construct in.

Comment: @rubenvb: Sorry, that was not as clear as it should have been. I do not see a way how I could turn this into a template (using C++98) without either losing the ability to daisy-chain outputs (as in my second example), or having to come up with a convoluted mess to handle any number of parameters and parameter types.

Comment: @DevSolar: wouldn't `inline template<class T> std::string SSTR( T x ) {  return dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >( (std::ostringstream() << std::dec << x) ).str() }` do? (Haven't tested, but I do wonder what would go wrong and why?

Comment: @rubenvb: It would do for an individual `int` (my first example). But without the `ostream` visible to the compiler in `main` (as it is hidden within the template function), it will try to look up `operator<<()` for `const char []` in my second example - which will croak. I know the OP asked only for an `int`, but this more generic macro is so useful (and actually quite widespread) that I thought I'd include it here.

Comment: For the versatility I prefer a template function. For the daisy-chain perhaps that can be handled in the same function with a bit of RTTI ...

Comment: @neuro: Well, write one up. I for one dislike macros myself, but this one is quite well-defined and well-behaving. And if the alternative is some as-yet-unavailable template function that "somehow" does the trick with lots of additional code *and* a reliance on RTTI, I believe the fine line between good practice ("avoid macros where possible") and fundamentalism ("avoid macros AT ALL COSTS!") has been crossed.

Comment: @DevSolar: Well daisychaining is nice, but I would write it like this: `std::string s2( "i: " + SSTR(i) + ", x: " + SSTR(x) );` which in my opinion is faster (less streaming operators) and more expressive (you're not passing everything, including the `const char*` s to the function in question. What I love C++ for these pedantic discussions `;)`

Comment: @rubenvb: Less streaming operators? Yes, one less. (You still have the std::dec in there.) Four streaming operators as opposed to my five. At the cost of an additional temporary `ostringstream` object, an additional `str()` call, and three `operator+()` calls, and it gets worse the longer the daisy-chain gets. ;-) Plus, I don't get what you are talking about re "passing everything to the function in question". I do not see where you are saving anything in that ballpark.

Comment: @DevSolar: Well, your macro is streaming everything right of the last stream operator inside it (ie the `const char*` s are also passed to the function/macro in question). Well, I may well be wrong here, but still, I did provide an inline function template alternative IMHO.

Comment: @rubenvb: I think there is some misunderstanding of the inner workings going on here, on your side. It's a macro, so there is no "passing". And as I said, my macro allows daisy-chaining, which is how streams are supposed to work in C++. Your template, on the other hand, does not, and is thus not a viable replacement IMHO.

Comment: @DevSolar: Ok, You're right. My poor template skill can not code The extra capability of SSTR("i = " << x); And I totally agree with your statement about fundamentalism ^^ You get a +1 from me. Greetings to your C64 ;)

Comment: @neuro: I wish I still had one. I'm going along quite well with VICE though. Oh, and I *do* still have an Amiga A600 in the basement. You want? ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: Well thank you, but I still have an old A500 that probablty does not work anymore, but my old A1200 worked well some 5 years ago :) I just miss my old Sinclair ZX81. Sorry for your C64 ;)

Comment: @DevSolar boost::lexical_cast is faster: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

Comment: @Catskul: That might be. But there are places where Boost might not be an option.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function to convert `int` to `std::string` after including `<sstream>`:

```
#include <sstream>

string IntToString (int a)
{
    stringstream temp;
    temp<<a;
    return temp.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While `std::to_string` is a straightforward tool that should be kept in mind, starting with C++20, you may include [`<format>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format), which allows for more elaborates conversations from `int` to `string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <format>

int main()
{
    using std::cout, std::endl;

    auto const n = 42;
    cout << std::format("{}", n) << endl;
    cout << std::format("{:d}", n) << endl;
    cout << std::format("{:#x}", n) << endl;
    cout << std::format("{:#o}", n) << endl;
    cout << std::format("{:#b}", n) << endl;
}
```

output:

```
42
42
0x2a
052
0b101010
```

Answer (score 0):

You might include the implementation of itoa in your project.
Here's itoa modified to work with std::string: http://www.strudel.org.uk/itoa/

Answer (score -3):

Suppose I have `integer = 0123456789101112`.  Now, this integer can be converted into a string by the `stringstream` class.

Here is the code in C++:

```
   #include <bits/stdc++.h>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
      int n,i;
      string s;
      stringstream st;
      for(i=0;i<=12;i++)
      {
        st<<i;
      }
      s=st.str();
      cout<<s<<endl;
      return 0;

    }
```

Comment: were not similar but more complete answers already given many years ago?

Comment: Yeah, but this answer is perfect i think as i didn't get any effective answer from previous.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Here, is another easy way to convert int to string

```
int n = random(65,90);
std::string str1=(__String::createWithFormat("%c",n)->getCString());
```

you may visit this link for more methods
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-best-way-in-c-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string/