# Writing a abstract function turns integer into string

Tags: c++, stl, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

```
class MyInteger
{
   MyInteger() : m_val(0) { }
   MyInteger()( int _val ) : m_val( _val ) {}
  ~MyInteger() {}
};

MyInteger myInteger(10);
std::string s = (std::string)myInteger
```

How can I write C++ function to get "10" in s??
I am new to C++.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: also - you don't need to define the destructor in your case, the default is enough, and you don't have the `m_val` member. Also, to convert `MyInteger` to `std::string` by casting as you do you need to define a casting operator. Or you can define a `to_string()` member function.

Answer (score 3):

you could have a method

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
//...

std::string MyInteger::toString()
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << m_val;
    return stream.str();
}
```

or to fit your style:

```
class MyInteger 
{
public:
    MyInteger() : m_val(0) { }
    MyInteger()( int _val ) : m_val( _val ) {}
   ~MyInteger() {} 

   std::string toString()
   {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << m_val;
        return stream.str();
   }

private:
   int m_val;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above methods you can overload the casting operator like this:

```
class MyInteger
{
  ...
  operator std::string() { /* string conversion method here */ }
};
```

as stated in the following link
[Overload typecasts](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/)