# Simple C++ - about strings and concatenation and converting int to string

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

I have a question about Visual C++ Strings. I want to concatenate the next string.

```
for (int i=0; i<23; i++)
{
    imagelist.push_back("C:/x/left"+i+".bmp");
    imagelist.push_back("C:/x/right"+i+".bmp");
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << "C:/x/left" << i << ".bmp";
imagelist.push_back(os.str());
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use stringstreams:

```
#include<sstream>

for (int i=0; i<23; i++)
{
    stringstream left, right;
    left << "C:/x/left" << i << ".bmp";
    right << "C:/x/left" << i << ".bmp";
    imagelist.push_back(left.str());
    imagelist.push_back(right.str());
}
```

`stringstream` is not the faster in performance solution, but is easy to understand and very flexible.

Another option is to use `itoa` and `sprintf`, if you feel at home with c style printing. However, I have heard that `itoa` is not very portable function.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i<23; i++)
{
    imagelist.push_back("C:/x/left"+std::to_string(i)+".bmp");
    imagelist.push_back("C:/x/right"+std::to_string(i)+".bmp");
}
```