# inserting int variable in file name

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

How can I insert int variable while creating .vtk file? I want to create file at every k step.
i.e. so there should be series of files, starting from file_no_1.vtk, file_no_2.vtk, ... to file_no_49.vtk .

```
while(k<50){
  ifstream myfile;

  myfile.open("file_no_.vtk");

  myfile.close();

  k++;
}
```

Comment: Dupe of all of the `How to convert int to string?` questions here. Just so you know, there's a `std::to_string` function in C++11.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C++11:

```
while(k<50){
  ifstream myfile("file_no_" + std::to_string(k) + ".vtk");
  // myfile << "data to write\n";
  k++;
}
```

Comment: +1: `std::to_string`? That's neat.

Comment: @Zeta, I was ecstatic when I saw someone here mention that and `std::stoi`, but depressed when I found out my implementation doesn't have either >.>

Comment: @chris: I recall it was me who mentioned `std::stoi` and you commented on my post. :-/

Comment: @Nawaz, It very well might have been. Thank you if it was, as at least I can recommend it to others :)

Comment: Not the first time I stole I good idea from @Nawaz.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) (include `<sstream>`):

```
while(k < 50){
    std::ostringstream fileNameStream("file_no_");
    fileNameStream << k << ".vtk";

    std::string fileName = fileNameStream.str();

    myfile.open(fileName.c_str());

   // things

    myfile.close();

    k++;
}
```

Comment: I want to point out that there was a question recently that used `myfile.open (fileName.str().c_str());`, causing the confusion. Make sure not to do that, and instead make the string variable.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
char fn [100];
snprintf (fn, sizeof fn, "file_no_%02d.vtk", k);
myfile.open(fn);
```

Or, if you don't want the leading zero (which your example shows):

```
snprintf (fn, sizeof fn, "file_no_%d.vtk", k);
```

Comment: +1 despite the potentially confusing variable names

Comment: @SamIam: Is `fn` for filename confusing?

Comment: `MAGIC_BUFFER_SIZE`? Hideously unsafe `sprintf`? You should be ashamed of yourself for posting this as a C++ answer.

Comment: @wallyk  it's certainly harder to recognize than say... `fileName` would be.

Comment: @DeadMG:  Okay, it is fairly well improved.  Magic buffer size:  hrrmmpph!  It is right there to see for excellent maintenance.

Comment: @wallyk: No. The only acceptable buffer size is "The one I computed was necessary".

Comment: @DeadMG: There is absolutely no chance of a problem occurring by using `snprintf` in this way.

Comment: @DeadMG:  Simplest thing that can possible work FTW!!!!

Comment: @DeadMG:  you are adding needless complexity to avoid a problem which is easily detected.  In the process, you are contributing to a less maintainable body of code.

Comment: @SamIam: Except it won't work, because tomorrow some intern will edit the string to be longer than 100 characters, and you will bite UB. Rob's answer is the most concise, most maintainable, and guaranteed correctness.

Comment: @SamIam:  Point taken.  But also see [beauty in brevity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4351938/198536)

Comment: @wallyk  Point taken?  I didn't have a point that was contrary to yours

Comment: @SamIam:  I thought your point was that `fileName` is more readable than `fn`.