# inserting int into file name using stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am using c++ 98 (as that is what is installed on the university server). I am trying to save an output to a file. The filename has to be dice_N.dat where N is the number of rolls of the dice, which I have called n_trials. I have tried following the suggestions on [inserting int variable in file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437702/inserting-int-variable-in-file-name). When using the second suggestion I get the output N.dat. Here the snippet of my code which tries to do this:

```
    ostringstream fileNameStream("dice_");
    fileNameStream << n_trials << ".dat";
    string fileName = fileNameStream.str();  
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(fileName.c_str());
```

I can't use `to_string` as this is not supported in c++ 98

Comment: You can create your own `template <class T> std::string ToString(const T& x) { std::ostringstream ss; ss << x; return ss.str(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
ostringstream fileNameStream("dice_", std::ios_base::ate);
```

Specifies stream open mode as `ate`

See [here](http://rextester.com/EUHP60108)

Comment: What is the reason for `ate`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears because the std::stringstream overwrites the initial buffer.

Try this instead:

```
ostringstream fileNameStream;                    // let this be empty
fileNameStream << "dice_" << n_trials << ".dat"; // and pass "dice_" here
string fileName = fileNameStream.str();  
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(fileName.c_str());
```

Alternately, you can create the ostringstream with `std::ios::ate` as a flag (`ate` tells the stream it should append at the end of the input (and then, you can still pass the "dice_" part in the constructor and it will not be overwritten).

Answer (score 1):

```
ostringstream ss;
ss << "dice_" << n << ".dat";
myfile.open(ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: That should be `std::ostringstream`, but otherwise, this is the route I would have taken.  (I always construct `std::ostringstream` empty.  Somehow, it seems more logical; an output stream doesn't have any content until you inject it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) to create a `std::string` from the `int`, then concatenate.
In fact, I would just make the whole filename this way

```
std::string fileName = "dice_" + std::to_string(n_trials) + ".dat";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I can't use 'to_string' as this is only supported in c++ 11 not 98.

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide all three parts with the `<<` operator, it is also more readable since you don't mix different syntaxes:

```
ostringstream fileNameStream;
fileNameStream << "dice_" << n_trials << ".dat";
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your int with boost:

```
boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(yourint) from boost/lexical_cast.hpp
```