# Assigning Variable to CreateFileA file name

Tags: c++, winapi, bmp, createfile, lpcstr

I'm creating a .bmp file using this CreateFileA method

`HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA("Screenshot01.bmp", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);`
At the moment is static and just keeps re-writing the old file.

I want to call this method multiple time, each time it will create a new file with a different file name, for example

"Screenshot01.bmp"
"Screenshot02.bmp"
"Screenshot03.bmp"
etc.

It doesn't have to increment, but the file name should be different each time.

How do I change the file name each time the method is called?
Are you able to assign the File name to a Variable?

Comment: _"Are you able to assign the File name to a Variable?"_ Of course you are! Did you try it? Did it work? If not, what was ther error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [inserting int variable in file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437702/inserting-int-variable-in-file-name)

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question, I admit this was a simple question, I was just confused with the different types of CreateFiles and the different types of parameters they accept. Next time I'll research more before posting since I'm still a noob at C++, but thank you for the quick replies and solutions (This is a great community).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `std::string`. For instance:

```
#include <string>
....
std::string filename = "Screenshot01.bmp";
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(filename.c_str(), ...);
```

To build the file name up from an integer you might do this:

```
#include <string>
....
std::string filename = "Screenshot" + std::to_string(id) + ".bmp";
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(filename.c_str(), ...);
```

> How do I change the file name each time the method is called?

Keep track of the most recently used id value, and increment it when you need a new value.

Comment: Thank you works perfectly. I didn't know you had to redeclare the variable data type when concating; thought it would work by string filename = "foo" + "bar";