# How to use variables for path directory for saving a file?

Tags: c++

I have to save a .txt file in a folder. I have given the directory but it involves more then 1 variable. Here is the code:

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(("c:\\User\\Taha Mukhtar\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApplication3\\ConsoleApplication3\\Folder"+fileNumber+"\\"+fileName);
```

The `fileNumber` and `fileName` are variables of the type int and string respectively. 
Please tell me the correct syntax.

Comment: Convert fileNumber to string and then concat with others.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437702/inserting-int-variable-in-file-name

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the "fileNumber" int variable to a std::string with std::to_string(). Also even if you're on Windows you can just use a single forward slash instead of doubling the backslashes.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("c:/User/Taha Mukhtar/source/repos/ConsoleApplication3/ConsoleApplication3/Folder" + std::to_string(fileNumber) + "/" + fileName);
```