# How to convert intptr_t to string

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Does anyone know how to do that conversion?

I need to concatenate a intptr_t type to a string, and therefore need to convert it.

It's not an int, as It's a 64 bit OS.

Correct me if I'm wrong
Thanks

Comment: It's the same as an `int64_t` then, most likely. Look it up on the header files to see what it's `typedef`'d as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << ip;
ss.str();
```

(or if you prefer:

```
ss << std::hex << ip;
```

)

Answer (score 2):

`intptr_t` is just a number. Therefore:

- [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)
- [...and others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2b%2b%20convert%20int%20to%20string)
- [Converting numbers to strings and strings to numbers](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D9j2Nwbp/)

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
std::to_string(ip);
```

Well, simple if you have C++11.