# convert integer to string for function parameter

Tags: c++, string, integer, converters

I have a function which accept a string parameter and I have an integer variable then I should convert it to string and then pass it to that function I used this code but as ostringstream is for I/O it doesn't work.

```
ostringstream ostr;
while (.....)
{
regnum++;
ostr<<regnum;
grph.addlastname(ostr.str());
}
```

for example it pass 12345 to function instead of 5,what should I do?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: There are dozens of SO questions on this already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c

Comment: std::to_string, Boost lexical_cast, ...

Comment: I said I want for example pass 5 to function but instead it pass 12345 this is the problem

Comment: guys this way doesn't work for me

Comment: @EYx: You need to stop saying "it doesn't work" and learn to be precise. _Describe_ what happens. Apply some analytical thought! Because we are not psychic after 4pm.

Answer (score 5):

It's true - there are a lot of similar questions which solve "What's the best way to do this?" but I think that there's something to learn for the OP in the answer to the question of "Why does this not work?"

Therefore:

Your `stringstream` has an internal state, and during your loop you always append a new digit - but the previous ones are still in the stream! You can fix this by making the `stringstream` scope-local to the loop, i.e. declaring it inside the loop rather than outside of it.

(`std::to_string` is still the better solution for this particular problem, though.)

Comment: Good spot. I failed to parse the question at all.

Comment: yeah your first opinion worked!Tnx alot

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine except one thing,
see:

```
ostringstream ostr;
 while (.....)
{
 regnum++;
 ostr<<regnum;
 grph.addlastname(ostr.str());
}
```

Your declaring your ostr outside the while, the first time that while runs, it adds '1' to the ostr, the second time, because it's the same "ostringstream" variable, it adds '2', so your string will be '12' now...

Solution: Declare ostringstream ostr, inside your while, use std::to_string, or do a ostr.clear() every time that the while ends. (The best way si declaring your ostr inside your while)