# Comma Formatting for numbers in C++

Tags: c++

I'm needing help in adding commas to the number the user enters, some guidance or help would be appreciated. So far I have it where i store the first three digits and the last six digits and then simply format it.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main ( int argc, char * argv[] ) 
{
unsigned long long userInput;
int fthreeDigit;

cout << "Enter a long long number: " << endl;
cin >> userInput;

fthreeDigit = ( userInput / 1000 );
userInput %= 1000;

cout << "Your Number: " << fthreeDigit << "," << userInput << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: so you have it or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to achieve where any number can be inputted. The way I currently have it doesnt allow it to happen

Comment: give an example with numbers

Comment: no, that it simply reads in the numbers user inputs and formats them with a comma.

Comment: Yes, all those work but unfortunately, I'm unable to substr(), can only use modolus and division.

Comment: correct, so 123456 = 123,456 and 12 = 12 and 1234567 = 1,234,567.

Comment: wow sorry, yes your correct 12345, should out put as 12,345

Comment: I guess you actually mean 12345 should output 12,345 since you said "inserting a comma in every thousand". so 123456 =123,456; 12=12, 1234=1,234, which is what we usually do. Is this right?

Comment: That is correct apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @JL22 look at my new solution, it is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the brute force but may be easiest to understand way to get every thousand digits with the help of a vector.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main ( int argc, char * argv[] ) 
{
    long long userInput;
    int fthreeDigit;

   cout << "Enter a long long number: " << endl;
   cin >> userInput;
   vector <int> res;  //use vector to store every 3 digits
   while (userInput !=0)
   {
     fthreeDigit = userInput %1000;
     res.push_back(fthreeDigit);
     userInput = userInput / 1000 ;
   }

   std::reverse(res.begin(), res.end());
   for (size_t i = 0; i < res.size()-1; ++i)
   {
     if (res[i] ==0)
     {
        cout << "000"<<",";
     }
     else
     {
       cout << res[i] << ",";
     }
   }

   if (res[res.size()-1] == 0)
   {
       cout << "000";
   }
   else{
       cout << res[res.size()-1];
   }
   cout <<endl;
   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

I tested this code with the following case:

```
Input: 123456 Output: 123,456
Input: 12     Output: 12
Input: 12345  Output: 12,345
Input: 1234567 Output: 1,234,567
Input: 123456789 Output: 123,456,789
Input: 12345678 Output: 12,345,678
```

I guess this is what you want according to your response to comments.

Comment: yes, thats exactly what Im looking for thank you, though would there be a more simple way of doing it, reason I'm asking is im still pretty new to the language.

Comment: You are welcome, the way I tried was trivial and simple already. Do you mean a faster way?

Comment: IMHO, the way I showed is actually very fast and efficient. you have to extract those 3 digits anyway.

Comment: Yeah, looking over it again your right, again I cant thank you enough for the help.

Comment: What about `1000000`? Is it going to print `1,0,0`?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Thanks for pointing that out, just updated the code. now it should work as expected.

Comment: @SongWang look at my new solution, it is much better I think

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you need?  The locale will do this for you correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char * argv[] ) 
{
  unsigned long long userInput;
  int fthreeDigit;
  cout << "Enter a long long number: " << endl;
  cin >> userInput;
  std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
  std::cout << userInput << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the One True answer for globalization AND simplest source code. Other countries don't use commas.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

Comment: True that! This code is the simplest and most direct and doesn't require iterating through the numbers manually.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
I have two solutions. first without playing with numbers (**recommended**) and second (division).
first solution is:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct my_facet : public std::numpunct<char>{
        explicit my_facet(size_t refs = 0) : std::numpunct<char>(refs) {}
        virtual char do_thousands_sep() const { return ','; }
        virtual std::string do_grouping() const { return "\003"; }
};

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout<<"before. number 5000000: "<<5000000<<endl;

    std::locale global;
    std::locale withgroupings(global, new my_facet);
    std::locale was = std::cout.imbue(withgroupings);

    cout<<"after. number 5000000: "<<5000000<<endl;

    std::cout.imbue(was);

    cout<<"and again as before. number 5000000: "<<5000000<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> > before. number 5000000: 5000000
> >     after. number 5000000: 5,000,000
>
> and again as before. number 5000000: 5000000
>
> RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 54ms)

and second (not recommended) is :

```
double f = 23.43;
std::string f_str = std::to_string(f);
```

or this

```
int a = 1;
stringstream ss;
ss << a;
string str = ss.str();
```

Then you can use `string::substr()` `string::find()` `string::find_first_of()` and similar methods to modify and format your string.
[a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

---

If you really want (have to) divide: (I think my version is cleaner & more efficient than the others)

```
unsigned long long userInput;
    std::stringstream ss,s0;
    std::string nr;
        std::cout << "Enter a long long number: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> userInput;
        int input=userInput;
        int digits;

        while(input>999){
            input=input/1000;
            digits=userInput-input*1000;
            int mdigits=digits;
            while(mdigits<100){s0<<"0";mdigits*=10;}
            std::string s=ss.str();
            ss.str("");
            ss<<","<<s0.str()<<digits<<s;
            userInput=input;
            s0.str("");
        }

        std::string sf=ss.str();
        ss.str("");
        ss<<input<<sf;

        std::cout << "Your Number: " << userInput << ";" << digits <<";"<<ss.str()<<std::endl;
```

> Enter a long long number:  12345678 Your Number: 12;345;12,345,678

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string commify(unsigned long long n)
{
  string s;
  int cnt = 0;
  do
  {
    s.insert(0, 1, char('0' + n % 10));
    n /= 10;
    if (++cnt == 3 && n)
    {
      s.insert(0, 1, ',');
      cnt = 0;
    }
  } while (n);
  return s;
}

int main()
{
  cout << commify(0) << endl;
  cout << commify(1) << endl;
  cout << commify(999) << endl;
  cout << commify(1000) << endl;
  cout << commify(1000000) << endl;
  cout << commify(1234567890ULL) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/kVHRQh)):

```
0
1
999
1,000
1,000,000
1,234,567,890
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Accepts a long number, returns a comma formatted string
CString num_with_commas(long lnumber)
{
    CString num;
    num.Format(%d",lnumber);
    if(num.GetLength() > 3) {num.Insert(num.GetLength()-3, ',');}
    if(num.GetLength() > 7) { num.Insert(num.GetLength()-7, ','); }
    if (num.GetLength() > 12) { num.Insert(num.GetLength()-12, ','); }
    return(num);
}
```