# Concatenating two string

Tags: c++, string

I have read numerous posts as to why two string literals cannot be added in C++, etc, and the operator+ support adding a string literal to an integer.

However, I am trying to understand the compiler error in the following code:

```
string str1, str2, str3;
int i = 10;

str1 = "Hello " + i;
str2 = i + "Mars";
str3 = "Hello " + i + "Mars";
```

Initialization of `str1` and `str2` works fine, but the construction of `str3` gives the following error:

> example.cpp: In function `int main()`:
>   example.cpp:20:27: error: invalid operands of types `const char*` and `const char [5]` to
>   binary `operator+`

Q1: In the error message, I understand `const char [5]` refers to `"Mars"`. What does `const char*` refer to, the integer `i` after conversion to a `char *`?

Q2: `operator+` has left-to-right associativity, I am guessing the construction of `str3` can be written as:

```
str3 = ("Hello " + i) + "Mars";
```

Does `("Hello " + i)` evaluate to a `char *`?

Q3: In the following code:

```
str5 = string("foo ") + "bar ";
str6 = string("foo ") + "bar " + i;
```

Setting of `str5` compiles fine, but `str6` generates loads (page and half) of error messages. What is the outcome of `string("foo ") + "bar "`, is it a `"string"`?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: You are trying to add a string and an integer.  That's the error.  Consider : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`str1` takes the string literal (really an array of constant characters), decays it to a pointer to the first character, and adds ten to that pointer, resulting in a `const char *` that's outside of your string literal, which is undefined behaviour, since it's beyond one past the end.

`str2` does the same thing as `str1`, but goes even farther out of bounds.

`str3` does the same thing with `"Hello"` and `i`, and then tries to add the resulting `const char *` to your other string literal (again, an array of constant characters, which is decayed due to being passed into a function). There's no overload of `operator+` that will take `const char *` and `const char *`, thus you get errors.

Take note that none of these will work as you want them to. The ones that do compile are undefined behaviour. `std::string` has overloaded `operator+` to suit its purposes, so adding a string literal to a `std::string` just concatenates it. To add an integer is a bit ambiguous, though (and thus not supported with `operator+`), so you have to make your intent clear by converting it to a string first:

```
str6 = string("foo ") + "bar " + std::to_string(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Q1: In the error message, I understand const char [5]' refers to "Mars". What doesconst char*' refer to, the integer i after conversion to a "char *"?

It refers to the result of `"Hello" + i`.

> Q2: operator+ has left-to-right associativity, I am guessing the construction of str3 can be written as:
>   str3 = ("Hello " + i) + "Mars";
>
> Does ("Hello " + i) evaluate to a char *?

Yes. It evaluates to `const char*`, though.

> Q3:  What is the outcome of string("foo ") + "bar ", is it a "string"?

Yes, it's a `std:string`. You get an error in `str6 = string("foo ") + "bar " + i;` because you can't add a string and an integer.

A side note - none of the following three statements is iniatialization:

```
str1 = "Hello " + i;
str2 = i + "Mars";
str3 = "Hello " + i + "Mars";
```

They all call assignment operator.

Comment: However it is valid to add a string literal to an integer (as seen by setting of str1 in my main post).  I am curious, as to why that was not implemented, adding a string to an integer.

Comment: @AhmedA, For `std::string`, do you want to increase its length by that number? Concatenate the number? Add a character with that numeric value? It's really better as a separate operation. As for the literal, it takes on the necessary pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @AhmedA It's valid, but only if you're not adding more than the length of the literal (see chris's post). It does not do concatenation, though, it increments the pointer to the literal.

Comment: Please ignore my last question, figured out the outcome of adding an int to an string literal.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, "Hello" the literal is treated as a char*.  You can do pointer arithmetic on a char* by adding an int to it -- you're saying "10 chars beyond what the char* points to".  In other words, garbage.

In short, you need to be using boost::lexical_cast or istringstream for this kind of thing.

Comment: Ah ok, I just noticed when I printed "Hello" + 10, it is not "Hello" + "10", but as you pointed out, the value is garbage.  Thank you.

Comment: @AhmedA try `std::cout << ("Hello" + 1) << std::endl;` to get a clearer understanding of what happens.