# return value of a bool function and passed pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to C++ having trouble in assigning value to char* of a function. I have a function as below which returns bool

```
bool Function(char* inString)
{
        int m = strlen(inString);
    char output[1001];
    memset(output , 0 , sizeof(output));
    sprintf_s(output,50,"length is %d",m);

       if(m>5)
        return true;
    if(m<5) 
        return false;

}
```

Along with the function , i am trying to get the "output" value on calling this function outside  defined local inside this function which has value - "length is -"

I tried doing

```
 bool Function(char* inString)
{
int m = strlen(inString);
    char output[1001];
    memset(output , 0 , sizeof(output));
    sprintf_s(output,50,"length is %d",m);
    sprintf_s(inString,50,output);
  if(m>5)
            return true;
        if(m<5) 
            return false;
}
```

But this fails because inString has already a value and this is giving following error
Access violation writing location 0x00165267.

Is there any way to get both parameters from this function ( bool value based on string length) as well as b) the string statement "output"?

I appreciate your help..

Comment: And if `m==5`? Your functions doesn't cover returns for all possibilities.

Comment: m==5 is file-not-found obviously: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Comment: If it's C++, avoid C strings, and (generally) pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you calling this function?  If you're calling it with a string literal, then that string literal is likely in read-only memory.  For example, this will fail:

```
bool result = Function( "longer than 5" );
```

That will likely result in an access violation because the string `"longer than 5"` is likely in read-only memory.  (It's not required to be, but it's likely with modern compilers.)

Also, as Alexandru pointed out above, you didn't handle the m==5 case at all.

Edit:  If you want to get the string you're generating with `sprintf_s` out of the function, you have a couple options.

1. You could add a second parameter with a buffer to print the string into.  Instead of declaring a buffer on the stack (your `char output[1001]`), you could instead have this pointer passed to you.  ie. your function prototype becomes `bool Function(char *inString, char *outString);`
2. Make your buffer `static`, and then return a pointer to it by reference.  That requires you to add a second operand.  This one is a bit uglier:  `bool Function(char *inString, char **outString);`  Then, inside your code you say `*outString = output`, which is, frankly, gross.
3. Move your output buffer to a file-scope array.  That's even uglier.

One of the advantages of #1 above is that you can use default arguments and an if-statement to make the `sprintf` optional:

```
bool Function(char *inString, char *outString = 0)
{
    int m = strlen(inString);

    if (outString)
        sprintf_s(outString, 50, "length is %d", m);

    return m >= 5;
}
```

Also, a stylistic note:  Prefer `char *inString` to `char* inString`.  In C and C++, the asterisk is not part of the type being declared, but rather a modifier on the individual symbol being declared.  If you want to declare two character pointers `a` and `b`, you write `char *a, *b`, not `char* a, b`.

Edit 2:  If you believe John Carmack's insistence that you `const` anything that could be `const`, then the above becomes:

```
bool Function(const char *const inString, char *const outString = 0)
{
    const int m = strlen(inString);

    if (outString)
        sprintf_s(outString, 50, "length is %d", m);

    return m >= 5;
}
```

I suppose you could go further and make it return `const bool`, except the function's return value is already an rvalue...

Comment: Yeah, most compilers would catch and optimize that.  I'll go ahead and edit my answer above, though.

Comment: If you ever find a compiler that *doesn't* "optimize" that, it's time to throw that compiler away. But Roddy's suggestion isn't a performance optimization, it's a *readability* optimization.

Comment: I just find it more readable. Unless you happen to prefer `if ((m>=5) == true) ...` ;-)

Comment: @Roddy and @Cody Gray:  I agree with you that the more concise form is more readable.  I've worked with too many programmers, though, that need the longer, more-spelled-out form, sadly.  They get confused when they see you returning a comparison as a value, as if comparisons are only valid inside an `if`, `while` or `for`.  This isn't Pascal, folks.

Comment: Awesome! Thats impressive answer. I was exactly looking for this solution. Thanks Joe and everyone!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to return a string from the function. You need the string to be allocated in such a way that it is alive even after you exit the function. Your example stores the string in a local array(`output`), which does not live beyond the scope(`{ }`) of the function.

There are several ways to do this:

- Dynamically allocated memory
- `static` storage

and so on, which one to use depends on your usage semantics.

You just need to pass the output string as a function parameter. Since you want to allocate the string inside the function you need to pass a pointer by reference.

On a side note, consider using `std::string` instead of a `char *`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using c++ you should do something like

```
bool Function(std::string &inString, std::string &outString)
{
    size_t size = inString.size();
    outString = "length is " + std::to_string(size); //if c++11
    if (size > 5)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

to convert your size_t to string in C++ you can use `boost::lexical_cast` or this [define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

```
#include <sstream>
#define SSTR( x ) dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >(( std::ostringstream() << std::dec << x ) ).str()

 inString = "length is " + SSTR(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not really C++, it's C.

Here's how you should do it in C++. Note the use of references rather than pointers.

```
bool Function(const std::string &inString, std::string &outString)
{
  int m = inString.size();

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "length is" << m;

  outString = ss.str();

  return m >= 5;
}
```