# C++ Error in converting int to string

Tags: c++, string, output

When I try to convert an int to string it produces weird results which I don't know where it comes from, here's a code snippet:

```
if (!ss.fail() && !ss.eof()) {
    ss.clear();

    string operand1 = "" + num1;
    string operand2 = "";
    getline(ss,operand2);   
    operand2 = trim(operand2);

    cout << num1 << endl << operand1 << endl;
    return expression_isvalid(operand1) && expression_isvalid(operand2) && operator_isvalid(c);

}
```

ss is a stringstream, num1 is an int, while c is a char.

basically the input is an expression like "1 + 1", num1 contains the first int it finds in that expression (using ss >> num1)

what I don't get is that this part

```
string operand1 = "" + num1; // assume input is "1 + 1" so num1 contains the value 1
...
cout << num1 << endl << operand1 << endl;
```

outputs

```
1
exit
```

I have no idea where the "exit" comes from, the word changes depending on the input, "exit" becomes "it" when I input "3+1", and "ye," when I input "13+2".

Comment: probelm with writing probelm in the title? :)

Comment: Yup. And problem with overflowing buffers and stuff. (That random string seems to come from invalid memory to me -> UB.)

Comment: I'm not sure: do you want to convert input int to string, or create calc that gets string expression and return values as strings?

Comment: `"" + num1` --- this does **not** convert an integer to a string (in fact it results in an undefined behavior, which is why you are getting weird output). You neeed to find out how to convert an integer to a string correctly. You have two wild guesses left, after that you have to open a C++ manual and read.

Comment: `num1` is an `int`, and you're adding that to the logical base address of a `const (&char)[1]`. You realize that is *not* the way to append the *text* translation of an `int` to a string, right? You're essentially doing pointer math on a const char buffer.

Comment: I want to convert the int into a string, basically this is a part of a recursive function that checks whether an expression is a valid infix expression

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **strtoul** function of std. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/) you can find a good documentation.

An example may be:

```
static unsigned long stringToInt(const string& str) {
  const char* cstr = str.c_str();
  char* endPtr = 0;
  return ::strtoul(cstr, &endPtr, 0);
}
```

Comment: or you could suggest something more C++ like and avoid strtoul completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringstream` to convert various types in `string`. I generally use the following template to do that:

```
template <typename T>
static std::string strfrom(T x)
{
    std::ostringstream stream;

    stream << x;

    return stream.str();
}
```

Then to convert an `int i` into a `string i_str`, just do:

```
i_str = strfrom<int>(i)
```