# How to: Typecasting Pointers on c++

Tags: c++, pointers, typecasting-operator

I am learning typecasting.

Here is my basic code, i dont know why after typecasting, when printing `p0`, it is not showing the same address of `a`

I know this is very basic.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a=1025;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<"Size of a in bytes is "<<sizeof(a)<<endl;

    int *p;//pointer to an integer
    p=&a; //p stores an address of a
    cout<<p<<endl;//display address of a
    cout<<&a<<endl;//displays address of a
    cout<<*p<<endl;//display value where p points to. p stores an address of a and so it points to the value of a

    char *p0;//pointer to character
    p0=(char*)p;//typecasting
    cout<<p0<<endl;
    cout<<*p0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are learning it wrong.

Comment: What is you actual output? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload of [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), used with `std::cout` and `char*` as arguments, is expecting a  null-terminated string. What you are feeding it with, instead, is a pointer to what was an `int*` instead. This leads to undefined behavior when trying to output the `char*` in `cout<<p0<<endl;`.

In C++, is often a bad idea to use C-style casts. If you had used `static_cast` for example, you [would have been warned](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7dd493d831a1d76) that the conversion your are trying to make does not make much sense. It is true that you could use `reinterpret_cast` instead, but what you should be asking yourself is: why am I doing this? Why am I trying to shoot myself in the foot?

If what you want is to convert the number to string, you should be using [other techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5590381/493122) instead. If you just want to print out the address of the `char*` you should be using [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof):

```
std::cout << std::addressof(p0) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a `char *` pointer to the `<<` operator of `std::cout`, it prints the string that the pointer points to, not the address. It's the same behavior as the following code:

```
const char *str = "Hello!";
cout << str; // Prints the string "Hello!", not the address of the string
```

In your case, `p0` doesn't point to a string, which is why you're getting unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said cout is interpreting the char* as a string, and not a pointer

If you wanted to prove that the address is the same whatever type of pointer it is then you can cast it to a void pointer

```
cout<<(void*)p0<<endl;
```

In fact you get the address for pretty much any type other than char&

```
cout<<(float*)p0<<endl;
```

To prove to yourself that a char* pointer would have the same value use printf

```
printf("%x", p0);
```