# C++ String to Integer Issue Using atoi(str.c_str())

Tags: c++, arrays, string, integer, atoi

I am trying to represent a variable in the form of a string to a integer, I have done so using;

```
atoi(str.c_str())
```

The string is originally obtained from a text file and stored into a;

```
CharArrayPtr cmemblock;
```

Which is then represented as a string;

```
    string str;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberofvalues; i++)
    {   
        str = cmemblock[i];
        int number = atoi(str.c_str());
        cout << number;


    }
```

If I was to change the 'cout' to print str;

```
str = cmemblock[i];
int number = atoi(str.c_str());
cout << str;
```

The number show correctly as stored in the text file

However, I require the output to be an integer so that I could represent it in a loop to search for a value stored in a array. So this is where 'number' comes into play, which is the reason why I am asking for your help, when;

```
cout << number;
```

Whenever a new line is read it is represented as '0' how would I go about removing this? If your require my full code it is in several different .cpp files and to prevent anyone copying my work I can only email it you, im sure you have already guessed it is part of a University Assignment.

Using Member Adosi code I came up with this;

```
         std::string str;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberofvalues; i++)
    {   

        str = cmemblock[i];
        std::stol(str);
        int number = std::stoi(str);
        cout << number;


    }
```

I get an error R6010. Have I done this wrong?

Comment: Why would you call `atoi` from C++? `atoi` is really appalling. Nobody wants to call `atoi`.

Comment: lol what do you suggest?

Comment: Fix your string! You cant blame the function for not working correctly if you pass illformed input. "1234" is a number, "1234\n" IMO not.

Comment: Almost anything other than `atoi`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Comment: @NoobProgrammer See my edit regarding your new error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::stoi(str)`

Use this instead of `atoi`

C++11 has this and a few other functions such as `std::stol()` for longs, `std::stof()` for floats, etc.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: I have tried using this method I get the following error; R6010 - abort() has been called

Comment: @NoobProgrammer Are you compiling with a C++11 enabled compiler?

Comment: Should have checked that apologies, no im using visual studio 2010, ill use the methods listed below. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it possible to add in a C++11 compiler to visual studio 2010?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer Its probably easier to simply upgrade and use VS2012 or 2013. Nathans suggestion will work on VS2010. I only gave one possible way of doing it on the off chance you had boost installed. For quickness sakes, just use a stringstream

Comment: Even outside of this one question it will be worth it in the long run to upgrade to C++11 via new Visual Studio (Express is free, by the way). The myriad of additional features and goodies largely outweigh the trouble of having to change versions.

Comment: I've just upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 im getting the same error; R6010

Comment: @const_ref I've just upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 im getting the same error; R6010

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have `C++11` for `std::stoi` but do have `boost` you could use [lexical cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html)

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main() 
{
    std::string s = "100";
    try 
    {
        int n = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);
        std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;
    } 
    catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast) 
    {
        std::cout << "conversion failed" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This ensures a valid conversion can take place and throws an exception if it cannot

**Regarding your Edit - This requires a C++11 Compiler to work**

```
std::string str;

for(int i = 0; i < numberofvalues; i++)
{   

    str = cmemblock[i];
    //std::stol(str); -> This line is unneeded as it converts string to a long
    // Ideally you should check that str is valid here etc. before changing it to an int
    int number = std::stoi(str);
    cout << number;


}
```

Comment: How would I get boost? Looks very interesting

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `std::stringstream`:

```
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string>

 int string_to_int(const std::string &string) {
     std::stringstream s(string);
     s >> number;
     if (!s.good()) {
         throw std::exception();
     }
     return s;
 }

 int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
     int number = string_to_int(argv[1]);
     return 0;
 }
```

This doesn't require any external libraries or C++11, and should be compatible with any C++ compiler out there.

**Edit**

Fleshed out the example to show how you could write your own `string_to_int` function to simplify the use of `std::stringstream`.