# Have a string as an integer

Tags: c++, integer, extract

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    int b=10;
    cout << a+b;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a problem with the code above. I know it's wrong, but it shows my point.

I'm wondering if I get a number as a string, how can I have it as an integer? For example, I give `12` to the program after running. So `a` will be `"12"`. Now I want the summation of 12 and the variable `b`. What should I do? How can I extract 12 as an integer from my string?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: Is `a` required to be a `string`? Can you just change it to `int`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/convert-string-to-int-c

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560588/c-string-to-integer-issue-using-atoistr-c-str

Comment: @SukkoPera: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6154614/103167) is about 20 times better.

Comment: If it's wrong, then how does it show your point? By your own admission, your code _doesn't do what you want it to do_. So, expecting us to be able to use it to magically divine what you want it to do, seems like quite optimistic thinking.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Fair enough :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, you can use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    int b=10;
    cout << stoi(a)+b;
    return 0;
}
```