# return string with persistence buffer

Tags: c++, g++

I tried to write a function that formats a value into string. However, i encounter issue with its persistence.

```
using namespace std;

string string_format(const string &msg, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char text[BUFF_SIZE] = { 0, };
    va_start(ap, msg);
    vsnprintf(text, BUFF_SIZE - 1, msg.c_str(), ap);
    text[BUFF_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
    va_end(ap);

    return string(text);
}

int main()
{
    char* p1 = (char*)string_format("%d", 123).c_str();
    char* p2 = (char*)string_format("%d", 45).c_str();

    printf("value: p1=%s, p2=%s\r\n", p1, p2);
}
```

The above will print:

> value: p1=45, p2=45

instead of

> value: p1=123, p2=45

I wrote the code this way because i want to keep 2 or more char* instance at the same time. return "new string(text)" works, but i dont want to keep writing "delete"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Comment: the format does not necessarily to be int, it can be
    char* p1 = (char*)string_format("%s", "hello").c_str();
    char* p2 = (char*)string_format("%s", "world").c_str();

in which it will print: value: p1=world, p2=world

Comment: Why recreate `sprintf`?

Comment: i was trying to make my code more readable. since there are a lot of string need to be formatted, i was thinking of a function to create one line formatting + assigning:  
  
`stA.buff1 = string_format("%s", "how").c_str();`    
`stA.buff2 = string_format("%s", "are").c_str();`    
`...`

Comment: @Va1iant it causes undefined behaviour to have a reference type as the last parameter before the `...` . You need to either take the string by value, or take `char const *`.  The fact that it appears to work currently is no guarantee that it'll keep working as you add more things to your program.

Comment: @Brandon, this version could be improved to allocate the right amount of space; unlike `sprintf`.  (There are some non-standard self-allocating versions of `sprintf` around, of course)

Comment: @MattMcNabb; EDIT: Oh that semi-colon makes all the difference. I see what you mean now.

Comment: A very similar problem in another SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464504/string-and-const-char-and-c-str/23464576#23464576

Answer (score 2):

When you use `c_str()` you're getting a pointer to an internal buffer in the string. That pointer is only valid as long as the string object is still alive. You're taking a pointer to a temporary string object that's immediately getting deleted, which causes the incorrect behavior. The reason it manifests as "persistence" is probably because the two very similar strings just happen to use the same memory space. Accessing the pointers after the string has been destroyed is undefined behavior in any case.

If you want to use `c_str`, you need to store your resulting strings into proper `string` variables and keep them there for as long as you need the pointer.

Or even better, don't deal with `char *` at all. Since you're using C++, use proper string objects for your strings always.

Answer (score 2):

Store the results in a `string` and use `.c_str()` when you need.

```
string p1 = string_format("%d", 123);
string p2 = string_format("%d", 45);

printf("value: p1=%s, p2=%s\r\n", p1.c_str(), p2.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the quick and clear response. To achieve my original objective (make my code more readable, since this kind of buffer assignments are common in the module i'm writing), I ended up using a macro that declare a string as a temporary placeholder. This time it shows the correct result

```
#define ASSIGN_BUFFER(var, format, value) \
    string str_##var = string_format(format, value) \
    var = (char*)str_##var.c_val()

string string_format(const string &msg, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    char text[BUFF_SIZE] = { 0, };
    va_start(ap, msg);
    vsnprintf(text, BUFF_SIZE - 1, msg.c_str(), ap);
    text[BUFF_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
    va_end(ap);

    return string(text);
}

int main()
{
    char *p1, *p2;

    ASSIGN_BUFFER(p1, "%d", 123);
    ASSIGN_BUFFER(p2, "%d", 45);

    printf("value: p1=%s, p2=%s\r\n", p1, p2);
}
```

Comment: This still has the problem pointed out by Matt: “it causes undefined behaviour to have a reference type as the last parameter before the `...` ”

Comment: could you explained the reason of the undefined behavior? and why it would be different if i put string/const char* instead

Comment: Unfortunately, the only explanation is: because the standard says so. It’s defined in §18.10/3 but no explanation is given. The most likely explanation is that this is a C language mechanism which only exists in C++ for reasons of backwards compatibility. The proper C++ way would be to use [variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), which is better anyway.

Comment: that's fair enough. Actually i put the parameter as "const string &msg" because i saw it from another stackoverflow thread. But i guess if the standard say so, better to comply than sorry. Thanks for bringing out the concern i would otherwise overlooked