# how to get a string using a string and integer?

Tags: c++, string

I want to get output some thing like this..

```
Word_1
Word_2
Word_3
.
.
.
Word_1234

etc...
```

I have seen `sprintf` and `itoa` etc to format string, to convert int to string. In case of `sprintf` I have to declare size.
With `"Word_"+itoa(iterator_variable)`, I think I can get what is needed. But is there any better way to get the desired output?

Comment: What is wrong with your second option `"Word_"+itoa(i)`?

Comment: If I remember correctly, in C++ you can just concatenate numbers to a string using the `+=` operator. If you just want to output the strings and don't have to remember them, you can probably get away with `printf("%s%d\n",string.c_str(),int);` or `cout << string << int << endl;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight Yes, but you have to convert the `int` to a `string` first. Which is why OP used `itoa`

Comment: @Cyber I clicked "Add Comment" prematurely, I remembered there was some more I meant to add. I've updated my comment

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight: You don't remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to C++11 you could use `std::to_string()`

```
std::string s = "Word_";
std::string t = s + std::to_string( 1234 );
std::cout << t << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using c++ I like to use boost::format and boost::lexical_cast to solve these sort of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend stringstreams, as they allow any strings, streams, and arithmetic types (among other things) to be concatenated into a character representation.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n1 = 3;
    int n2 = 99;
    std::stringstream ss;

    // all entries in the same stringstream
    ss << "Word_" << n1 << std::endl;
    ss << "Word_" << n2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << ss.str();

    // clear
    ss.str("");

    // entries in individual streams
    std::string s1, s2;
    ss << "Word_" << n1;
    s1 = ss.str();
    ss.str("");
    ss << "Word_" << n2;
    s2 = ss.str();
    std::cout << s1 << std::endl << s2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```