# Insert integer in an array C++

Tags: c++, char

I wrote the following code to convert string of type 'aaadddbbbccc' to 'a3d3b3c3' :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

    void stringCompression(char *str,char *newStr){
        int a[256] = {0};
        int newCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str) ; i++){
            int j = str[i];
            if (a[j] == 0 && strlen(newStr) <= strlen(str)){
                a[j] = 1 ;
                newStr[newCount] = str[i];
                newCount++;
                int count = 0;
                for (int n = i; n < strlen(str); n++){
                    if(str[i] == str[n]){
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                }
                newStr[newCount] =(char) count;
                newCount++ ;
            } else if (strlen(newStr) > strlen(str)){
                strcpy(newStr,str);
            }
        }
    }

    int main() {
        char str[] = "abcdabcdabcd";
        char *newStr = new char[strlen(str)+1];
        stringCompression(str,newStr);
        cout << newStr;
        return 0;
    }
```

My problem is at step

```
newStr[newCount] =(char) count;
```

even though it is inserted but the output is not `a3b3c3d3` but `a*squarebox*b*squarebox*c*squarebox*d*squarebox*`. squarebox being 2*2 matrix with one value as the number that is desired. I am using eclipse IDE. 
. I would really appreciate your help. How can I correct this. Am I using the correct approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming `count` is a **simple** digit, you may use `newStr[newCount] = static_cast<char>('0' + count);`.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you really don't want to use `strlen` in the condition of the loop.  C style strings are designed for access through the pointer, so your outer level loop should be something like `for ( char const* p = str; *p != '\0'; ++ p )`, with `*p` to access the characters.

Comment: And of course, using the `char` converted to an `int` is not going to work for all characters, at least not if `char` is signed (which is often the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
newStr[newCount] =(char) count;
```

converts the number "count" into the character corresponding to that number according to the ascii table (http://www.asciitable.com/), which is "end of text" for "3", that does not correspond to any number.

You should convert "count" into a string instead. See here for example:
[Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

However, be aware that it might be longer than one digit, for example if count is "11", it will take two letters in string representation.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have to use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/ to convert integer to char string

Comment: Not a very reliable reference, but they do point out that `atoi` is a sometimes thing---it's not standard, and not all compilers support it.