# Convert built-in data type to std::string: memcpy vs snprintf

Tags: c++, string, undefined-behavior, memcpy

I have referred to the [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c) and other posts before this. I am also aware that `std::to_string()` is the best way (but it's not available in few platforms).

While **experimenting**, I came across a weird issue with `memcpy()`. For the example sake, assume that we always pass built-in data types (`int`, `char`, `long`) to below function:

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string (const T& value)
{
  std::string s(16, 0); // Max size captured
  ::memcpy(&s[0], &value, sizeof(value));
  return s;
}
```

Running this function individually in a sample program works fine. But while plugging into a bigger code base, somehow it gives weird results! i.e. it gives spurious values. (Ubuntu 14.10, g++4.9 -std=c++11)

However, if I convert the above program using `sprintf()`, it works fine.

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string (const T& value)
{
  std::string s(16, 0); // Max size captured
  s[::snprintf(&s[0], "%d", value)] = 0;
  return s;
}
```

**Question**:

1. Am I touching undefined behavior with `memcpy()` (or even
   `sprintf()`)?
2. Would byte ordering influence this code?

Comment: You may want to look into stringstream, boost also has convert functions in C++... `memcpy()` and `snprintf()` are fine when properly used, but that's not very C++-esque.

Comment: That being said, `memcpy()` does not convert your number to ASCII. So yeah, you have to use `snprintf()`, but no `&` in front of value.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, thanks for pointing the typo. It was indeed `value` and not `&value` with `sprintf()`. This is experimental, hence wanted to know why `memcpy()` doesn't work. Is the ASCII thing the reason?

Comment: `memcpy(&s[0], &value, sizeof(value))` won't result in the text representation of the value if it is an `int`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap, yes, you do not want to use `memcpy()`. Using `snprintf()` you avoid having to convert the number to ASCII yourself. Something like this would probably be preferable though:

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string (const T& value)
{
  char buf[16];
  ::snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", value);
               // ^-- size was missing in your example
  return buf;
}
```

However, you have a big flow in this function because you cannot know what T is going to be. It could be a double and `"%d"` won't work as expected. Similarly, it could be a string (`char const *`).

If you want to manually convert a number to ASCII you can use a loop, something like this:

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string (T value)
{
  char buf[16]; // any int number is less than 16 characters
  char *s = buf + sizeof(buf);
  *--s = '\0';
  do
  {
    *--s = value % 10 + '0';  // conversion to ASCII, 1 digit at a time
    value /= 10;
  }
  while(value > 0);
  return s;
}
```

WARNING: that function does not properly handle negative numbers. I'll let that one as an exercise for you to handle as required.

Now, if you want to use a C++ way that should work on all systems you mentioned, without boost or C++11.

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string (T const& value)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << value;
  return ss.str();
}
```

In this case the stringstream knows how to handle T whatever T is, numbers, objects, etc. as long as those things understand the `<<` as in `std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;`.

If you check out one of my project, named [as2js](https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/as2js/), you'd see a file named include/as2js/node.h which declare something like this:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, Node const& node);
```

That means you can later create a node and print it like this:

```
Node n;
std::out << n << std::endl;
```

This means your to_string() function would work with my Node objects.

You can find the implementation of all of that under lib/node_display.cpp

Comment: I am aware of `stringstream` solution. Anything new/better in C++11?

Comment: Yeah... in C++11 the `to_string()` is built-in: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: Ok, it's `std::to_string()`. As mentioned in the post, not all compilers/platforms support it. e.g. Android's version.