# how to print a longvariable on a message box (in c++)

Tags: c++, winapi

I wrote this code to calculate the score of a student on the Greek entrance exams. When the program calculates the score and saves it in the variable `moria`, I want the number to appear in a pop-up window.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
```

The last part, where the score is calculated and the message-box code comes up, is this:

```
mathks= mathk*0.7 + mathkp*0.3 ;
aodes= aode*0.7 + aodep*0.3 ;
fysks= fysk*0.7 + fyskp*0.3 ;
aeps= aep*0.7 + aepp*0.3 ;
ek8eshs= ek8esh*0.7 + ek8eshp*0.3 ;
mathgs= mathg*0.7 + mathgp*0.3 ;
gvp=(mathks+aodes+fysks+aeps+ek8eshs+mathgs)/6 ;
x=mathk*1.3 ;
y=fysk*0.7 ;
moria=(gvp*8+x+y)*100 ;
string moria2 = to_string(moria);
MessageBox(NULL, moria2, "arithmos moriwn", NULL);
```

To print the number which is a long, I think I have to turn it into a string first. But it still won't work, and I get the following errors:

1. 'to_string' was not declared in this scope
2. cannot convert 'std::string' to 'const CHAR*' for argument '2' to 'int MessageBoxA(HWND__*, const CHAR*, const CHAR*, UINT)'

Since I only recently started learning a few things about graphics, there might be some really dumb mistakes here, so please be understanding...

Comment: Should be `std::to_string()` and `moria.c_str()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ moira2.c_str() you mean.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Could well be, that question is so crappy it doesn't matter much though :-P ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem #1: converting an `int` to a `std::string`

`to_string` isn't declared, so the compiler doesn't know what you are trying to do. I'm going to assume `moria` is an `int` (or some number).

To convert an `int` to a `std::string`, you should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c) which highlights three great ways of doing so: [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/), [`std::ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/), and most recently and also the best [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) (which it appears you are trying to use).

To properly use `std::to_string`, you should write the following:

```
std::string moria2 = std::to_string(moria);
```

Note that `std::to_string` is only from C++11 which I assume you are using. If you do not have C++11 prefer `std::ostingstream`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << moria;
std::string moria2 = oss.str();
```

As a side-note, you should prefer to name your variables indicatively, not just appending numbers.

## Problem #2: converting a `std::string` to a `const char*`

Your second problem is that [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) takes a `const char*` as its second arguement, and you are providing a `std::string` (which the compiler cannot implicitly convert to); however, `std::string` gracefully provides you a way of doing so: [`std::string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/). Your code should thus be:

```
MessageBox(NULL, moria2.c_str(), "arithmos moriwn", NULL);
```

Or

```
MessageBox(NULL, std::to_string(moria).c_str(), "arithmos moriwn", NULL);
```

It's worth noting the two commenters @πάντα ῥεῖ (my apologies if this is incorrect) and @Jonathan Potter who first pointed this out.

Comment: The second argument to `MessageBox` is a `const TCHAR*`. If you want to pass a `const char*`, you need to call `MessageBoxA`. Ideally, though, you'd call `MessageBoxW` and use a `std::wstring`.

Comment: It would seem your advice sold the second error (thanks a lot for that), however when i use the function to_string i get the following errors: if i used std::to_string then it says to_string is not a member of std, and if i dont it says to_string was not declared in this scope. So i am kinda stuck here :/

Comment: @VlassisFotis: As the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) explains, you'll have to `#include <string>`.

Comment: Well... i am  not that dumb. Obviously i included it, but could i , perhaps, have an older version of it or something where the to_string is not included?

Comment: @VlassisFotis `std::to_string` is C++11 (see the link). If you are not compiling with C++11 I suggest you use `std::ostringstream` (there's an example in the linked question)

Comment: Thanks! But in the end i included the funtction definition itself in the code and it worked. Thanks a lot for your advice though, i will keep it in mind for my next problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not included `<string>`, therefore `to_string()` was not declared.

The problem 2 is already resolved by the above answer.