# Why should declaring a stringstream turn up an error of an "incomplete type"?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I am trying to declare a stringstream to use to reverse a number to see if it is a palindrome (input is an int passed into the function)-

```
stringstream ssInput;
ssInput << input;
string reverseInput = ssInput.str();
```

I modeled it after this question -

[Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c?lq=1)

Why am I getting this error?

> aggregate 'std::stringstream ssInput' has incomplete type and cannot
>   be defined| ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s),
>   0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: Which headers do you include? Does it work if you #<include sstream>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you included

```
#include <sstream>
```

? It should also be needed  to add using namespace std or to use fully qualified name std::stringstream instead of simply stringstream.