# C++ variable/looping issue

Tags: c++, loops, variables

No idea where the issue is coming from so I will insert the whole sub-routine.
When you insert a string into the guess space it will loop infinitly, if you insert a number it will return "ion do you want to go?"(which isn't even written anywhere in the program).

```
void guess(){
int guess;
string guess2;
string guess_status="";
bool win;
int attempts;
int counter;
int num;
while (guess2 != "exit"){
    num=rand() %100 + 1;
    win=0;
    counter=0;
    while (win != 1){
        attempts=5-counter;
        cout << "Guess a number                Attempts Left: " << attempts << endl;
        cout << "between 1 and 100       ============================\n                              The Guesing Game\n                        ============================" << endl;
        cout << "\n" << guess_status << endl;
        cout << "\nGuess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        system("cls");
        if (!cin) {
            guess2=guess;
            if (guess2 != "exit"){
                guess_status="Please insert a valid number, restarted game.";
                win=1;
            }
        }
        if (cin){
            if (guess==num){
                win=1;
                guess_status="Correct! Generated new number.";
            }
            if (guess != num){
                if (guess < num){
                    guess_status=num +"was too low!";
                }
                if (guess > num){
                    guess_status=num +"was too high!";
                }
            }
        }

    }


}


}
```

The routine is indented, it just didn't paste that way

Comment: Step through it with a debugger.

Comment: @Zereges because it's very hard to use correctly (Alas! OP used it incorrectly too, which is not surprising.) It's got clumsy behavior with regards to whitespace handling, so it's best avoided.

Comment: `win=0;` when `win` is `bool`? Use `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int guess;
string guess2;
guess2=guess;
```

This is your problem. You can't convert an int into a string this way. What you're actually doing is telling the computer that guess2 is a string that starts at the memory address that the value of guess is currently. That's why you're getting a string output that's not even in your program- it's just what happens to be at that address.

See here for how to convert an int to a string:
[Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Also, don't use cin >> guess. Get the input as a string, then check to see if it can be converted to an integer.