# How to convert WORD type to string in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Could anyone explain how to convert WORD to string in C++, please?

```
  typedef struct _appversion
    {
        WORD            wVersion;  
        CHAR            szDescription[DESCRIPTION_LEN+1];
    } APPVERSION;

    // Some code
    APPVERSION AppVersions;

    // At this point AppVersions structure is initialized properly.

    string wVersion;

    wVersion = AppVersions.wVersion; // Error

// Error    1   error C2668: 'std::to_string' : ambiguous call to overloaded function   
    wVersion = std::to_string((unsigned short)AppVersions.wVersion);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c

Comment: @Petesh I am trying your solution and getting this error `Error 1 error C2668: 'std::to_string' : ambiguous call to overloaded functio...` Any clue how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `WORD` in Visual C++ context is a type-definition for `unsigned short`.

so you can use `std::to_string` for this task:

```
 wVersion = std::to_string(AppVersions.wVersion);
```

Edit:
 appearently Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support C++11 features completly, use `std::stringstream` instead:

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream <<AppVersions.wVersion;
wVersion  = stream.str();
```

make sure to include `<sstream>`

Comment: I am trying your solution and getting this error `Error 1 error C2668: 'std::to_string' : ambiguous call to overloaded functio...` Any clue how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: it compiles perfectly on my Visual Studio 2013, but I guess you can add explicit cast , e.g. `to_string((unsigned short)myWord))`

Comment: also, make sure you include <string> header, e.g. `#include <string>`

Comment: I have `#include <string>` included. And adding explicit cast does not help.

Comment: Done, please take a look

Comment: are you using Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @Dimi you might try casting to a type that is directly supported by `to_string`, I'd try `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It's C++, just tell wVersion that it's a char*

```
std::string((char*)&AppVersions.wVersion, sizeof AppVersions.wVersion /*or just 2*/)
```