# How can I insert integer into a string using insert function in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

Below `check` is string and `temp1->data` is integer. I want to insert `temp1->data` into `check`. So I type cast `int` into `const char*`. This gives `warning : cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]`

Part of code:

```
  temp1 = head;
  std::string check;
  check = "";
  int i = 0;
  while(temp1 != NULL)
  {
    check.insert(i, (const char*)temp1->data);// here is the warning
    temp1 = temp1->next;
    ++i;
  }
```

I want to know what other choices I have to insert the integer (`temp1->data`) into string(`check`) using insert function and what is the actual effect of warning [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] on my code.

## Points:

1. data is integer, next is pointer to Node
2. I'm trying to implement a function to check if a linked list containing single digit number is palindrome or not. Yes, I know other methods for this but I just want to implement through this method too.
3. Here I want to store all the data of linked list into a string and directly check if the string is palindrome or not.

This question may seem duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c) . But it is not, here I explicitly asked for inserting integer into string using insert function contained in string class.

PS: on using `std::to_string(temp1->data) gives me error ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you willing to insert a whole integer into a string or something else?

Comment: What is the nature of data, and why to you try to do this?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you are trying to do. E.g. are you trying to make the string contain a text representation of the number, or something else

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Comment: `to_string` will work if you add the proper `-std=` option to the compiler.

Comment: @StoryTeller edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::to_string` function to convert integer to string and then insert it in a string using insert function on `std::string`.

```
std::string check;
check = "";
int i = 0;

check.insert(i, std::to_string(10));
```

The reason you are getting error `"to_string is not a member of std"` is may be because you did not `include <string>` header.

Answer (score 0):

First, here's a way to convert an integer to a string without much work.  You basically create a stream, flush the int into it, and then extract the value you need.  The underlying code will handle the dirty work.

Here's a quick example:

```
stringstream temp_stream;
int int_to_convert = 5;

temp_stream << int_to_convert;
string int_as_string(temp_stream.str());
```

Here's more info on this solution and alternatives if you want to know more:
[Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Regarding the impact of the cast that you're doing, the behavior will be undefined because you're setting char* to an int value.  The effect won't be converting the int value to a series of characters, instead you'll be setting the memory location of what the system interprets as the location of first character of a char array to the value of the int.

Comment: This is anything but quick and easy.

Comment: @n.m. Fair criticism, updated the language to more literally describe the provided solution.