# How can I concatenate string + int + string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char

How can I concatenate i + name + letter + i?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){

    //I need a const char* to pass as a parameter to another function
    const char* name  = "mki";

    //The letter is equal to "A" for the first 2, "B" for the second 3,
    //"C" for the following 4 ...
    const char* final_string = ???
}
```

I already tried using:

```
std::to_string(i)
```

But I got an error saying that

> to_string is undefined for std

I'm using [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_versions).

Comment: use `std::stringstream`

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c/5590404#5590404) on a related (not duplicate) question. A macro version of Sam's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an older version of VC++ that does not support the current C++ standard. In that case, you have to do it the old-fashioned way.

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream o;

o << "mki" << i << "abc";

std::string s=o.str();
```

Answer (score -6):

plain old [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

```
char buf[10000];

sprintf(buf , "%s is %c string!!%d!!%d" , "this , 'a' , 1 ,1);
```

Comment: This solution is strongly discouraged. It's a C solution, not a C++ solution; and it is prone to buffer overflow (at the very least you should use `snprintf`).