# Converting an int to a string for a to_string method C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a lexical analyzer in C++ and have to include a `to_string()` method for my subclasses. This method won't be used by the lexical analyzer but we are told we have to include them for debugging purposes. The `to_string` methods I have written keep generating errors and I am not sure why. Here is what I have:

```
string *AddopToken::to_string()
{
   token_type_type tokenType = get_token_type();
   addop_attr_type addopAttr = get_attribute();
   return "[TOKEN TYPE: " + tokenType + ", ATTRIBUTE TYPE: " + addopAttr + "]";
}
```

This seems like it should work, but for some reason it does not.

Here is the typedef for `addop_attr_type` in the AddopToken header.

```
typedef enum addop_attr { ADDOP_ADD = 400,
                          ADDOP_SUB = 401,
                          ADDOP_OR = 402,
                          ADDOP_NO_ATTR = 499 } addop_attr_type;
```

So even though the type of `addopAttr` is `addop_attr_type`, all that really is is an int constant. I figured C++ could convert an int to a string. Is there a way to convert these variables to a string so my `to_string()` will work correctly?

Comment: Use `std::to_string(addopAttr).c_str()`

Comment: No, C++ never does anything for you. You have to do everything yourself. That's what makes C++ so awesome. Use `std::tostring()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't allow + for concatenation of string literals or string literals with integers.
The code you need is

```
char buff[1204];
sprintf(buff, "[TOKEN_TYPE; %d , ATTRUBUTE_TYPE %d ]", tokenType, addopAttr);

return std::string(buff);
```

You don't have to use the old C function sprintf, there are also lots of C++ functions people have invented for achieving similar things, and that gets rid of the temporary buffer, but at cost of being harder to follow what is going on underneath.

Comment: I tried this and the compiler wouldn't allow it. The error I got said `error: 'sprintf' was not declared in this scope` and the other was `error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char*> in return string(buff)`

Comment: #include <cstdio> to get sprintf. The other error is because you've asked for a pointer to a string instead of a string. In C++ you don't need to do that, it just makes the code harder to write. std;;strings are like variables, not like C strings.

Comment: We were given the code for the header files and in the header, as well as the super class, the `to_string()` methods return type was a pointer `string *`. We were told not to change that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Edit: now it returns pointer to a string, Don't forget to delete the pointer after you finish using it.

```
 std::string* AddopToken::to_string() const{

           token_type_type tokenType = get_token_type();
           addop_attr_type addopAttr = get_attribute();

           std::string* result = std::string();
           *result = std::string("[TOKEN TYPE: ") + std::to_string(tokenType) + std::string(", ATTRIBUTE TYPE: ") + std::to_string(addopAttr) + std::string("]");

           return result;
        }
```

C++ see "[TOKEN TYPE: " as char[14] and not as a string. And to convert int to string use std::to_string().

Comment: The method is defined in the super class as `string *` so we must deal with a pointer. How would that affect this?

Comment: Create a new pointer, point it to what you return now and return the pointer. But you will have to remember to delete the pointer when you are done with it.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I don't know why, but for some reason it keeps saying `error: no matching function for call to 'AddopToken::get_attribute() const'` I don't know why it says that because the `get_attribute()` method is defined and working correctly and it's not supposed to be a const method. Does the fact that the signature of `to_string` is `string *AddopToken::to_string() const {....}`

Comment: Yes, const functions must call const functions from the same class. you can use const_cast, but if you are allowed to change get_attribute() to const you do that.

Comment: When you define AddopToken::to_string(), it has to have the same signature as well, string *AddopToken::to_string() const { // Your code }.

Comment: It does have the same signature, In the header file it is listed as `string *` and in the class file I also have it as `string *`

Comment: If to to_string() initialized in the header file with const then when you define to_string() you have to define it with const.

Comment: I edited my code so it much to_string()`s initialization.