# cout a returned string

Tags: c++, string, cout

So I have my class called `array` and I want to return it as a formatted string, like this: `[first, second, third, ..., last]`. Now I wrote the method that is trying to do so:

```
std::string& array::to_string()
{
    char buffer[1];
    std::string s("[");
    for (auto &x: *this)
    {
        if (&x == this->end()) s += _itoa_s(x, buffer, 10) + "]";
        else s += _itoa_s(x, buffer, 10) + ",";
    }
    return s;
}
```

And yes, I've included `<string>`. Now, in the other part of my program I use `std::cout << myArray.to_string() << '\n'`. The error I get (during the execution) is just Visual Studio throwing me to `stdlib.h` header and showing this part of it:

```
__DEFINE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE_FUNC_1_1(
    _Success_(return == 0)
    errno_t, _itoa_s,
    _In_ int,  _Value,
         char, _Buffer,
    _In_ int,  _Radix
    )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error, and what line in your program does it come from? Step through your program with a debugger. Also, you probably need to show us more of your `array` class definition/implementation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `buffer` is too small.

Comment: Exactly from one of the lines from `if` statement (depending on the condition stated in if)

Comment: In C++, you should probably use [`std::to_string`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5591169/1848578) to convert numbers to `std::string`s

Comment: The tricky point is - I can't. Cannot use `std::`

Comment: But you are using `std::string`

Comment: Is that a restriction given in an assignment?

Comment: @Frynio you are ALREADY using std::  (std::string)

Comment: I cannot use `std::` algorithms and containters. As the lecturer said, I can use `std::cout and std::string`, cuz I should focus on algorithms, when implementing containers. And the buffer is too small, but that isn't the issue, tried with `buffer[50]`

Comment: @Frynio Your lecturer is contraddicting himself. std::string is a container.

Comment: @roalz, I know, he also said that we have to do it in a language compiled into native code, so we can do it in `C\C++` but in `C#` as well, which isn't, by default, compiled this way

Comment: @Frynio [facepalm] Poor guy! See my comment under my answer below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string `s` is local to the function `to_string`, and its destructor runs as `to_string` returns, so returning and using a reference to the already-destructed string creates *undefined behaviour*.  Return it *by value* instead:

```
std::string array::to_string() const
{
    // a more robust, C++-style implementation...
    std::ostringstream oss;
    size_t n = 0;
    for (const auto& x: *this)
        oss << (n++ ? ',' : '[') << x;
    oss << ']';
    return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: Did you pay attention to  tkausl's feedback too?  Separately, your loop will take you over the elements up to and excluding `end()`, which is *not* the last element but a sentinel value denoting "one-past-the-end" - so the `true` branch of your `if` statement is never executed.

Comment: `And the buffer is too small, but that isn't the issue, tried with buffer[50]`

Comment: @Frynio: perhaps give the implementation I've edited into this answer a spin....  (`#include <sstream>`).  As for why yours still isn't working, you're using Microsoft's non-standard function `errno_t _itoa_s` - note the return type is an error number and not a `char*` suitable for adding to a `std::string`: you should be checking the return value then adding `buffer`.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a reference to a std::string that is scoped inside your `array::to_string()` method.

When the method exits, the local `s` variable is out of scope, thus it is destroyed, resulting in a "[dangling reference](https://www.quora.com/What-is-dangling-reference)" being returned.

You should either return the string by value:

```
std::string array::to_string()
```

or pass it as a reference parameter:

```
void array::to_string(std::string& result)
```

Comment: Because you only have 1 character available in you "buffer" (char buffer[1];). Either use std::to_string(x) instead of that crappy buffer + _itoa_s(), or (due to your constraints) enlarge your buffer[]

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a reference to a local object. Because of this, you try to use an object that has been deallocated from the stack. Remove the `&` from the function signature to return it by value.

Comment: Still the same problem