# Complexity of Converting String to Int in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am having trouble with converting **string** datatype to **int** in c++, I am currently using DevC++ GNU version 5.8.3 which gives an error when i use **stoi**() funtion. My concern is not about conversion but about the complexity and how it is done. Code Below :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
int main(){
    string s="abc";
    int i=stoi(s,NULL,16);
}
```

> Error : 'stoi' was not declared in this scope

So, i wrote my own function, Code Below :

String to Int :

```
int strtonum(string s,int length) {
    int num=0;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        num=num*10+(int)s[i]-48;
    return num;
}
```

Integer to String :

```
string numtostring(int number){
    int digit=floor(log10(number))+1;
    string s="";
    for(int i=0;i<digit;i++){
        s+=(char)(48+number%10);
        number/=10;
    }
    reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
    return s;
}
```

Both Functions are giving desired output, But I am worried about the complexity of Conversion.

For String to Int it is : **O(n)**

For Int to String it is : **O(n)+O(n/2)**

**Q. Is there any better Solution to this problem ?**

**Q. How Complex are the Inbuilt Function**

**Q.How do they Convert one data type to another?**

Comment: So why did you tag C?

Comment: O(n)+O(n/2) is just O(n)

Comment: That code isn't portable. You can make it portable by replacing `48` with `'0'`.

Comment: Remember that for typical implementations, `long long` has a max just less than 10E19.  That means *n* is never more than 19 - which means it doesn't matter.

Comment: If you want to avoid the `reverse` operation, then as you know the length of the result, insert your generated chars from the end...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Comment: `numtostring` isn't going to handle zero well :-) - or negative numbers.  `strtonum` doesn't handle negative numbers, non-digits, or overflow.

Comment: Some tips: **1.** Don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31816096/13647419   **2.** Use `'0'` instead of `48` (more specifically, use the character itself instead of its ASCII code). It's easier to read, and I think not on all systems the characters have the same code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Error : 'stoi' was not declared in this scope
```

try to add "std::"

```
//stoi // x

std::stoi(...) // ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to use [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/?kw=atoi), and its complement [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/), or some related functions in this category.