# "+": cannot add two pointers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

OS: Windows 8.1 64bit | IDE: Visual Studio 2018

https://pastebin.com/6Lh6kABe -- if you need proper formatted code.

I'm developing a small command line tool to take screenshots using ADB. 
(Detail, ADB will be included in the same directory as the app; currently not there though.)

After fixing over 30 errors in my code that stopped the build process, now I'm here. An hour went by and I am not able to fix it, so I decided to ask you on here.

Here is the code:

```
    // ADBSS.cpp : Ten plik zawiera funkcję „main”. W nim rozpoczyna się i kończy wykonywanie programu.
//

#include <pch.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string filename;
    filename = "a";
    SetConsoleTitle(_T("*-_ ADB Screenshooter _-*"));
    std::cout << "+---------------------------------+" << endl;
    std::cout << "|ADB Screenshooter   [v1.0]       |" << endl;
    std::cout << "|Take screenshots from your device|" << endl;
    std::cout << "|with a simple CLI tool.          |" << endl;
    std::cout << "+---------------------------------+" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to ADB Screenshooter." << endl;
    cout << "Please input the filename: (The screenshot will be saved with that name)" << endl;
    cout << "DO NOT INCLUDE ANY SPACES IN THE FILENAME. Use only letters." << endl;
    cin >> filename;
    Sleep(4);
    system("cls");
    SetConsoleTitle(_T("*-_ Taking the screenshot _-*"));
    cout << "Trust your computer now if you haven't before." << endl;
    system("adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/ADBScreenshooter/" + filename.c_str() + ".png");
    Sleep(4);
    system("cls");
    SetConsoleTitle(_T("*-_ Copying to PC! _-*"));
    cout << "The file will now be copied to the location from where you run ADB Screenshooter." << endl;
    system("adb pull /sdcard/" + filename.c_str() + ".png");
    Sleep(4);
    system("cls");
    SetConsoleTitle(_T("*-_ Done! _-*"));
    cout << "Everything is done! Thanks for using ADBSS. Press any key to finish." << endl;
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Current errors are:

```
Ważność Kod Opis    Projekt Plik    Wiersz  Stan pominięcia
Błąd    C2110   "+": cannot add two pointers    ADBSS
```

Line 29 and 34.

Comment: `filename.c_str() ` -> `filename` in your `system` calls and let the C++ standard library work its magic.

Comment: @Bathsheba `system` expects a `const char*` so it will still get an error.

Comment: @NathanOliver: You'd put a c_str() around the temporary, as I know you know ;-)

Comment: Note that `system` with user input should be avoided to avoid exploit similar to [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Just to avoid confusing situations, you might want to filter the file name to remove any "funny" special characters, to be safe everything except `a-z A-Z 0-9 . _ -` to be safe (or dig out exact list of special chars for *cmd.exe* commands).

Comment: extra `\"` might allow to handle space: `system("adb shell screencap -p \"/sdcard/ADBScreenshooter/" + filename + ".png\"");`.

Comment: I'll bet you could remove 95% of that code and still show the problem.

Comment: If you consider one of the answers "correct", click the checkmark for that answer. This marks the question as "answered". Or clarify which part of your question remained unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

All your calls of the form

```
system("string1" + filename.c_str() + "string2");
```

need to be replaced with

```
system(("string1" + filename + "string2").c_str());
```

`"string1"` is a `const char[]` literal that decays to `const char*` when `+` is applied. `filename.c_str()` is also a `const char*` pointer. The compiler issues a diagnostic when you attempt to add two pointers, as that's meaningless.

Writing it the way I have forces `+` to be the overloaded `+` operator of the `std::string` class, which effects a *concatenation*.

My writing `c_str()` at the end extracts the data buffer from the anonymous temporary `std::string`, which is valid for the lifetime of the `system` function.

Comment: Aaaand guess what, [it worked!](http://despacito.solutions/iNy1oBWtT3a030Q.png) Gonna add this as the answer as soon as I can (6 minutes left right now)

Comment: `decltype(auto) system(const std::string& s) { return system(s.c_str()); }` to simplify call sites to `system("string1" + filename + "string2")`.

Answer (score 2):

A string literal is of type `char const[]` (which will decay to `char const *`). The return type of `c_str()` is `char const *`. `operator+()` is defined for `std::string`, but not for `char` pointers. You cannot add two pointers.

You can fix this by setting up the command in a `std::string`, and then calling `system( s.c_str() )` instead of putting together the command in-line:

```
std::string s( "adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/ADBScreenshooter/" );
s += filename;
s += ".png";

std::system( s.c_str() );
```

Comment: Any way I can bypass that?

Comment: @FalcoKażańII: Many. I added one to the answer.

Comment: @FalcoKażańII: A more swiss-army-knife approach of "putting a string together from various parts" (using `ostringstream`) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381).