# How to turn an int into a string?

Tags: c++, string, casting, integer

I've been trying to find how to do it online. I'm restricted from not using ready-made functions, like `to_string` or `boost::lexical_cast`, not even the `<sstream>` library. How can I do it with these limitations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

Comment: please learn to use the search function of this site or Google.

Comment: Maybe check this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c).

Comment: One digit at a time? I would guess whoever gave you the assignment with the restrictions also gave some guidance on how to start.

Comment: @JHBonarius Nope apparently, because I was told that the sstream isn't allowed, neither is to_string or anything else like that. I tried arguing that sstream is a needed input output library but NoOoOoO, you can't do that. It's really pissing me off tbh.

Comment: @RetiredNinja No, I wasn't given any guidance about it. As for the solution, do you mean casting it to a char and then string?

Comment: you have a stupid teacher ( I hate teachers that act they are teaching you C++, but don't allow you to actual use C++.). you can try `char` and doing `'0'+i` per digit... i.e. using the char for 0 and adding an offset.

Comment: @JHBonarius Oh man tell me about it, he's a real pain sometimes. Also thanks for the answer, appreciate it.

Comment: To be fair, I had to implement the equivalent manually once for a real-life program. Around 2005 or so. For underpowered cell phones.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel atoi or to_string should be a very efficient solution, so wonder how you would improve on that.

Comment: Well, you see, I was doing it in J2ME, and....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'0' + i` to get the char value of 0 and offset it. I.e.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int number = 12345678;

    int nrDigits = std::log10(number)+1;

    std::string output(nrDigits, '0'); // just some initialization

    for (int i = nrDigits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        output[i] += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }

    std::cout << "number is " << output << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Problems if number <= 0.  I would count the digits a different way.

Comment: @PaulSanders exercise for the reader ;) of course this is not the best solution. But it's not my assignment and i would just use to_string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
std::string int_to_string (int i)
{
    bool negative = i < 0;
    if (negative)
        i = -i;
    std::string s1;

    do
    {
        s1.push_back (i % 10 + '0');
        i /= 10;
    }
    while (i);
    
    std::string s2;
    if (negative)
        s2.push_back ('-');
    for (auto it = s1.rbegin (); it != s1.rend (); ++it)
        s2.push_back (*it);
    return s2;
}
```

I avoided using [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse), on the assumption that it would be off-limits.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0gwASKhFybUZdKv1)

Comment: This has UB when `i == INT_MIN`.

Comment: With teachers like his, iterators could as well be off limits, lol. Or `std::string`, and he'd want you to dynamically allocate a char array, hahaha.