# How to assign a string value to integer variable in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a very basic question how can I assign a string value to a variable that already has integer value. For example, int a = 10 then I need to assign a ='hey'. Is it possible in c++?

Comment: It is possible in C++, you can use `std::variant<int, std::string>`.

Comment: `'hey'` is a multicharacter literal, not a string. You can assign it to an `int`. That means `int a = 10; a = 'hey';` is valid in C and C++ but the result is implementation defined. Read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal

Comment: You could use some kind of container struct, which has a pointer to some buffer and a variable holding information about what type is. This way you could change the type. This is how python does it. I don't recommend it though as it's not very performant.

Comment: you can use `std::any` or `std::variant` but only where they're actually useful, use separate variables for separate things, its rare that the same thing needs to be 2 different types. What are you actually trying to implement? Please show a [mre]

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the actual problem you need to solve?`Why do you think you must assign a character or a string to an `int` variable?

Comment: I'm assigning a multicharacter to an integer

Comment: Yes we can see that, but *why?* What problem is it supposed to solve? Right now this is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Basically I'm comparing numbers and if one number is less than default Im substituting that number with 'NaN'

Comment: `std::optional<int>` sounds like a better option

Comment: Its just an exercise, but the point is that I tried to say a = 'NaN' but Im getting a random number(ASCII value of character)

Comment: It's not a random number. It's implementation defined but on most systems it's `'N' * 256 * 256 + 'a' * 256 + 'N'`

Comment: any idea what I can do to get actual value?

Comment: *Basically I'm comparing numbers and if one number is less than default Im substituting that number with 'NaN'* -- Even that explanation is XY Problem territory.  What is the *high-level* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: There is no problem, its just execrcise to practice and get better in cpp

Comment: The problem with multi-character constants is that they need to have an actual value, no matter how implementation-defined such constants are. So how do you differ from an actual valid `int` value and the value created by e.g. `'NaN'`? If you want an `int` value to be optionally "empty" or unset, then `std::optional<int>` (as mentioned by @AlanBirtles) is really a better way.

Comment: Here you can see how the value is calculated with GCC https://wandbox.org/permlink/xoUSHHNbL9ANPijX

Comment: as has been already pointed out, this is a XY problem. The solution to your problem "How to store a special value in a `int`, so I can distinguish 'no result' from 'result' ?" is not to store a string in an `int`. Instead of asking for that, better ask for the actual problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @ThomasSablik Multicharacter literals are conditionally-supported, so it may not be valid depending on the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are new to C++? In C++ you assign the variable a fixed type (`int` in your case). It is not possibile to change that type inside the scope. You have to convert `a` to a string and save them in a new variable. How to convert a string (char* or std::string) you can look here:

[Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)