# How do I turn an integer into a string?

Tags: c++

I want to write like this:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
if (x == 10) {
x = "A";
}
```

But I get this error message "error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int'"

Comment: Why are you trying to give `x`, which is an `int`, the value of `"A"`?

Comment: Once you've declared a variable, you don't get to change its type in C++.

Comment: It's not clear what you want but an assignment like that should be `x = 'A'`;

Comment: Having all the above comments in mind: `if (x = 10);` is functionally equivalent to `x = 10;`.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve? What should the program do?

Comment: You can't assign a char to an int. If you actually want to convert an int to a string, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c) already answers your question.

Comment: @Brent actually you can, what you can't do is to assign a `char*` to an `int`.

Comment: @Brent "_You can't assign a char to an int._" Char you could assign (a la `x = 'A';` is valid syntax). What you can't assign, however, is `char*`, as is attempted here,

Comment: BTW, you have a `;` following the `if` statement.  Usually, coding guidelines say to always use braces, `{` and `}` to avoid this pitfall.

Comment: Make sure your compiler warnings are turned on/up because compilers _will_ warn about that extra semicolon in the if statement and save you the headache of debugging it.

Comment: @rustyx I want to convert decimal numbers into hexadecimal. I take an input and divide it by 16, if the remainder is 10 the hexadecimal would be "A". 11 = "B" etc until 15 = "F".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Right thank you, I'm allways mixing python with c++

Comment: The easiest method is to read the number as an `int`, then output using `std::hex`.  You can also output to `std::ostringstream` if you want to convert to a hex string.

Comment: Use the [edit] button and add that info into the question itself so people can understand the intent.

Answer (score 3):

C++ has something called type checking, which basically means that you can't change the type of a variable (so if you define `x` as an int, you can't redefine it to a string). If you want to save the value of `x` as a string, you could do the following:

```
int x = 5;
std::string xAsString = std::to_string(x);
```

As a side note, you should use `==` in your if-statement to check whether two things are equal.

Comment: Right thank you, I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to do a program converting decimal numbers to hexadecimal. So I take an input and module 16. If the remainder is 10 then the hexadecimal would be "A", if its 11 it would be "B" etc until 15 = "F".

Answer (score 0):

From your comment below the first answer, if you are converting to a hexadecimal string, you can do it directly with `std::sprintf()` and a plain old C-string. See [std::printf, std::fprintf, std::sprintf, std::snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). You can do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define MAXHEXSTR 36

int main (void) {
    
    uint16_t u = 65535;
    char hexstr[MAXHEXSTR] = "";
    
    std::sprintf (hexstr, "0x%04x", u);
    std::cout << hexstr << '\n';
}
```

You can adjust the format string to meet your needs. Above it just formats the 16-bit value with a `"0x"` prefix and the conversion yields a 4-byte hex representation of the value zero padded as needed.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hexstrprintf
0xffff
```

or

A value of ten would yield:

```
$ ./bin/hexstrprintf
0x000a
```

Let me know if you have further questions.