# Function or library to create strings from every primitive data type and String?

Tags: c++

Is there a function to create strings or char[] by concatenating multiple types?

Something like:

```cpp
int int_type = 5;
float float_type = 3.14;
String string_type = "I'm";
char char_type = ' ';
char char_arr_type[9] = "a pirate"; 

String merged = x_func(int_type, float_type, string_type, char_type, char_arr_type);

// expected: "53.14I'm a pirate"
```

Comment: You can turn each argument into a string via [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), and then concatenate those individual strings. Alternatively you could `<<` each into a stringstream. What is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you!! Is there a line solution like the example? I need to pass a string to a logging function with some variables. This function is called multiple times in different ways in the code so I would like to have a "clean" way to call it

Comment: [`std::format`, `ostringstream` macro, ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5590404/60281)

Comment: I prefer absl::StrCat

Comment: With the damage Google has done to C++ with their "Style Guide", I am very reluctant with recommending anything that comes from their direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in c++17 you can use [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and string stream.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

template<typename ... Args>
string makeString(Args ... args)
{   
    stringstream ss;
    (ss << ... << args);
    return ss.str();
}
int main(){
    cout<< makeString("a b" , 1, "c d");
}
```

Output: a b1c d

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) for this purpose. It works almost the same way as printing all the variables to `std::cout`.
Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    // Your variables
    int int_type = 5;
    float float_type = 3.14;
    std::string string_type = "I'm";
    char char_type = ' ';
    char char_arr_type[9] = "a pirate"; 

    // Creating a new stream
    std::stringstream s;
    
    // Print all the variables to the stream
    s << int_type << float_type << string_type << char_type << char_arr_type;
    
    // retrieve the result as std::string
    std::string merged = s.str();
    
    std::cout << merged; // output: 53.14I'm a pirate
}
```

---

PS: I'm not sure what `String` in your code means, C++ only has `std::string`. Unless this is a typo you might have to do some casting or provide a custom `operator<<(std::ostream&, const String&)`.

Comment: Thanks!! My fault, I used the code from an Arduino sketch which use a different library for strings. Is there a build in one-line solution like the example?

Comment: @Wooble Ahh, ok, I don't know much about arduino. The accepted answer looks good however :)

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 and later, you can use [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format):

```
std::string merged = std::format("{}{}{}{}{}", int_type, float_type, string_type, char_type, char_arr_type);
```

In C++11 and later, you can use the [{fmt} library](https://fmt.dev) instead.