# C++ Casting out a int into string

Tags: c++, string, numbers, tostring

I am planning to change the elements inside the array of my `x[]` to cast out the number like 1, 2, 3, 4. But once i execute the code. it will show this error message.

```
error: no matching function for call to 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(int&)
```

Please anyone can help me to do anything to change my elements inside instead of using for loop? I can change it one by one by I want to change it all together just in case to save time and the amount of code written.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string x[] = {"X", "O", "X", "O"};

int main()
{
    cout << x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        x[i] = (string)i;
    }

    cout << x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead of casting to `string`. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26843934/11613622

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the reason of the error:

```
x[i] = (string)i;
```

read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string): how to use the function `std::to_string` so you can convert a number into a string

```
std::to_string(i);
```

---

```
#include <iostream>

std::string x[] = {"X", "O", "X", "O"};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Before: " << x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        x[i] = std::to_string(i);
    }
    std::cout << "after: " << x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] << std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

---

here the example: https://ideone.com/X4dEdz