# return the output value of a function that asks for an output variable

Tags: c++

Title is a bit messy, but i dont know how to simplify it. This is what i want to do:

```
nodeReceivedData[packetSize+1] = itoa(LoRa.packetRssi(), [output], 10);
```

`itoa()` always asks for a input variable, output variable and a size modifier. What I want to do, is to avoid having to make a temporary variable to then assign it's value to the actual variable I want that data to be. Is there something that can do this?

I also tried:

```
itoa(LoRa.packetRssi(), &nodeReceivedData[packetSize+1], 10);
```

but since `nodeReceivedData` is a `byte` type variable, `itoa()` won't accept it.

Extra info:

`int LoRaClass::packetRssi()`

`byte nodeReceivedData[50]`

Comment: What is `itoa` doing in C++ code? It's not even standard in C. What is the objective here? Why not [convert to `std::string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668760/converting-an-int-to-stdstring)?

Comment: `itoa(LoRa.packetRssi(), (char*)&nodeReceivedData[packetSize+1], 10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "itoa" expects the 2nd argument to be "char*" and 'nodeReceivedData' is byte (assuming it is just an "unsigned char"), you can just cast it to a char* and should work as expected:

```
itoa(LoRa.packetRssi(), (char*)&nodeReceivedData[packetSize+1], 10);
```