# converting integer to string C++

Tags: c++, itoa

I am trying to convert an integer to char array and I came across this piece of code

```
int i = 5;
std::string s;
std::stringstream out;
out << i;
s = out.str();
```

But when I try to print the value of `s` it still prints 5. I don't know if its supposed to do that or am I doing something wrong? Besides I would prefer if I could convert the same int to char array. But I would appreciate any help in the matter. 
Thanks!
Code taken from: [Alternative to itoa() for converting integer to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c)

Comment: What do you want it to print?  The textual representation of the number 5 is "5".

Comment: I was just trying to see what the textual representation would be. Does this mean if I try to convert any large numbers to text they would still be the same numbers? For example if I've -635997, what would that look like? Because right now it gives me same number

Comment: What else could it be?  What is the textual representation of -635997, if not "-635997"?  A given number has many possible textual representations; by default, you get the simplest and most familiar (decimal, no leading 0's).  There are flags you can set to get other representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Besides I would prefer if I could convert the same int to char array.

```
char *charPtr = new char[ s.length() + 1 ] ; // s is the string in the snippet posted
strcpy( charPtr, s.c_str() ) ;

// .......

delete[] charPtr ; // Should do this, else memory leak.
```

Comment: just wondering shouldn't the argument to strlen() be a char pointer? or would the string act the same way?

Comment: @Max Eastman : No, you're correct -- passing a `std::string` to `strlen` is illegal. It should be `new char[s.length() + 1];` or `new char[strlen(s.c_str()) + 1];`, but of course the second one is inherently less efficient.

Comment: @ildjarn - You are correct. Time for me to take rest, I guess :)

Comment: @Mahesh : `std::auto_ptr` uses `delete` rather than `delete []`, so `std::auto_ptr<char>` would cause undefined behavior here. On C++0x compilers `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` would be preferred; on older compilers, `boost::scoped_array` or `boost::shared_array` are the best options.

Comment: @Mahesh : Speaking of which, your code should have `delete [] charPtr;` rather than `delete charPtr;` ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn - Really, I am signing off for the day.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's supposed to do that. You'd (primarily) notice the difference from just printing a number out directly if you do some other string-type manipulation on the result (e.g., concatenating it with other strings, searching for characters in the string).

Just for example:

```
std::cout << i+i;   // should print "10"
std::cout << s+s;   // should print "55"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to stop worrying about issues like that you might be interested in [`boost/lexical_cast.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const int i=5;
  const char* s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i).c_str();
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```