# Convert Integer to String C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to itoa() for converting integer to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c)

I want to convert an `int` variable to `string` to put it in the `textbox`.

I have tried this code:

```
int x = 123;
std::ostringstream osstream;
osstream << x;
std::string string_x = osstream.str();
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: In what way is it useless? Have you checked the contents of `string_x` in a debugger?

Comment: What doesn't work? I know that this works for me.

Comment: what exactly is wrong with the above code?  That is how you would turn an integer into a string.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Does it not compile, and if so, what is the compiler error message? Does it segfault? Does it give some other string content than expected, and if so, what is it? I can't see why this code shouldn't work.

Answer (score -3):

Try using stringstream instead

```
std::stringstream osstream;
osstream << x;
std::string string_x = osstream.str();
std::cout << string_x << std::endl;
```

Works on my computer.

I had another issue once where I had to append a whitespace to that, so try this too:

```
std::stringstream osstream;
osstream << x << " ";
```

Comment: stringstream makes absolutely no difference in this usage. Also, it strikes me as horrible convention to name the variable osstream...