# Is boost::lexical_cast redundant with c++11 stoi, stof and family?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, std

Is `boost::lexical_cast` redundant now that C++11 introduces [`stoi`, `stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and family, or is there any reason to still use it? (apart from not having a C++11 compiler) Do they provide exactly the same functionality?

Comment: VS 2012's implementation of `stoi` and `to_string`, if I remember correctly, initialize a `stringstream` everytime. It is terribly inefficient.

Comment: @C.R. Regarding performance concerns, I [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23591010/2567683) an answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`boost::lexical_cast`

- handles [more kinds of conversion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html#boost_lexical_cast.performance.tests_description), including iterator pairs, arrays, C strings, etc.
- offers the same generic interface (`sto*` have different names for different types)
- is locale-sensitive (`sto*`/`to_string` are only in part, e.g. `lexical_cast` can process thousands separators, while `stoul` usually doesn't)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to summarize it best. And apoorvkul explains the reason for a generic interface quite nicely.

Comment: `lexical_cast` is also faster than than the standard library in many cases: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

Answer (score 21):

`boost::lexical_cast` gives you a uniform interface across types which is often very important in generic code.

In general, consistent interface across types for same functionality allows generic code better. For example, following can be used as generic parser from string tokens to std::tuple:

```
template<typename T>
void fill(T& item, const std::string& token){
    item = boost::lexical_cast<T>(token)
} 

template<int N, typename ...Ts> 
void parse(std::integral_constant<int, N>, std::tuple<Ts...>& info, std::vector<std::string>& tokens) {
    fill(std::get<N>(info), tokens[N]);
    parse(std::integral_constant<int, N - 1>, info, tokens); 
}

template<typename ...Ts> 
void parse(std::integral_constant<int, 0>, std::tuple<Ts...>& info, std::vector<std::string>& tokens) {
    fill(std::get<0>(info), tokens[0]);
}
```

Instead of tuple, I often use [boost fusion struct](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/define_struct.html) to deserialize some tokenized strings directly into a struct in a generic way.

Comment: Ok, but would it be possible to elaborate on that ? Some sample ?

Answer (score 5):

boost::lexical_cast is more than converting to a distinct set of types:

```
struct A {};
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const A&) {
    return stream;
}

struct B {};
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& stream, B&) {
    return stream;
}

int main(){
    A a;
    B b = boost::lexical_cast<B>(a);
}
```

Its strength and weakness is the acceptance of any pair of types for the conversion through an intermediate std::stringstream (where an optimized algorithm is or is not applied).

Answer (score 5):

Performance wise, you could do the comparison using the following code (it's a variation of my post [here)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23437778/2567683)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <exception>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;

// 1. A way to easily measure elapsed time -------------------
template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct measure
{
    template<typename F>
    static typename TimeT::rep execution(F const &func)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        func();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        return duration.count();
    }
};
// -----------------------------------------------------------

// 2. Define the convertion functions ========================
// A. Using boost::lexical_cast ------------------------------
template<typename Ret> 
Ret NumberFromString(string const &value) {
    return boost::lexical_cast<Ret>(value);
}

// B. Using c++11 stoi() -------------------------------------
int IntFromString(string const &value) { 
    return std::stoi(value);
}

// C. Using c++11 stof() -------------------------------------
float FloatFromString(string const &value) { 
    return std::stof(value);
}
// ===========================================================

// 3. A wrapper to measure the different executions ----------
template<typename T, typename F> long long 
MeasureExec(std::vector<string> const &v1, F const &func)
{
    return measure<>::execution([&]() {
        for (auto const &i : v1) {
            if (func(i) != NumberFromString<T>(i)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("FAIL");
            }
        }
    });
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------

// 4. Machinery to generate random numbers into a vector -----
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type
FillVec(vector<T> &v)
{
    mt19937 e2(1);
    uniform_int_distribution<> dist(3, 1440);
    generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&]() { return dist(e2); });
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value>::type
FillVec(vector<T> &v)
{
    mt19937 e2(1);
    uniform_real_distribution<> dist(-1440., 1440.);
    generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&]() { return dist(e2); });
}

template<typename T>
void FillVec(vector<T> const &vec, vector<string> *result)
{
    result->resize(vec.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        result->at(i) = boost::lexical_cast<string>(vec[i]);
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vi(991908);
    FillVec(vi);
    std::vector<float> vf(991908);
    FillVec(vf);

    std::vector<string> vsi, vsf;
    FillVec(vi, &vsi);
    FillVec(vf, &vsf);

    cout << "C++ 11 stof function .. " <<
        MeasureExec<float>(vsf, FloatFromString) << endl;
    cout << "Lexical cast method ... " <<
        MeasureExec<float>(vsf, NumberFromString<float>) << endl;

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "C++ 11 stoi function .. " <<
        MeasureExec<int>(vsi, IntFromString) << endl;
    cout << "Lexical cast method ... " <<
        MeasureExec<int>(vsi, NumberFromString<int>) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When [executed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3267c249004a9ea9) with

> g++ -std=c++11 -Ofast -march=native -Wall -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out

The results are

> C++ 11 stof function .. 540
>
> Lexical cast method ... 559
>
> C++ 11 stoi function .. 117
>
> Lexical cast method ... 156

The C++11 specialized functions certainly seem to perrform better. But they are exactly that, **specialized**, and as such make the construction of abstract interfaces harder than `lexical_cast`