# How to convert int to string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, int

I this a good way to convert int to string?

```
    int a = 123456789;
    string str = static_cast<ostringstream*>(&(ostringstream()<<a))->str();
```

Comment: Possibly looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c?lq=1, but that cast could be to a reference and spare the ugly pointer syntax.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 introduced [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) for this very purpose:

```
int a = 123456789;
std::string str = std::to_string(a);
```

Comment: Please do not answer obvious duplicates.