# Error Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c

I am quite new to C programming. I encountered this error while compiling my program. I have tried to look around the internet for a solution but to no avail. The error is on the line `num = rand()%20;`

```
char* getParameter(char *name)
 {
   char *num;

   char *buffer;


   if(strcmp(name,"Trainingsprogramm")){
    srand (time(NULL));
     num = rand()%20;;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}else if(strcmp(name,"Personnenummer")){
     srand (time(NULL));
      num = rand()%20;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}else if(strcmp(name,"Tretzustand")){
     srand (time(NULL));
     srand (time(NULL));
      num = rand()%20;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}else if(strcmp(name,"Tretleistung")){
     srand (time(NULL));
      num = rand()%20;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}else if(strcmp(name,"Drehzahl")){srand (time(NULL));
      num = rand()%20;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}else if(strcmp(name,"Geschwindigkeit")){srand (time(NULL));
      num = rand()%20;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}else if(strcmp(name,"GefahreneDistanz")){srand (time(NULL));
      num = rand()%20;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}else if(strcmp(name,"RealeKJoule")){srand (time(NULL));
      num = rand()%20;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}else if(strcmp(name,"AktuellerPuls")){srand (time(NULL));
      num = rand()%20;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}else if(strcmp(name,"MomentanerGang")){srand (time(NULL));
      num = rand()%20;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}else if(strcmp(name,"RelaxBetrieb")){srand (time(NULL));
      num = rand()%20;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}else if(strcmp(name,"VerbrauchteKJoule")){srand (time(NULL));
      num = rand()%20;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",num);
}

return buffer;

}
```

Comment: Change `char *num;` to `int num;`, Allocate memory for `buffer` , Call `srand` once at the start of `main`.

Comment: Why do you call srand continuously?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the star from the declaration of `num`.

```
char *num; // <<< This is a pointer to char declaration
char num; // <<< This is a char

int num; // <<< But this is probably what you meant/wanted!
```

Comment: thanks but i have a char buffer, that is why i chose the character pointer...is there another function that works like rand for characters and not integers. Thanks!!

Comment: Have a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228827/1667513) before looking up the first thing that popped into my head, which is [itoa](https://fresh2refresh.com/c/c-type-casting/c-itoa-function/). It's a simple function and you could even [implement it yourself](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdlib.h/itoa).

Answer (score 0):

> Assignment makes pointer from integer ...

```
 char *num;
 ...
 num = rand()%20;
```

The code tries to assign the integer result of [`rand()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html) to the character pointer `num`.

From the code you show so far, changing `num` to be an integer, like

```
 int num;
```

would solve this.

Comment: thanks but i have a char buffer, that is why i chose the character pointer...is there another function that works like rand for characters and not integers. Thanks!!

Comment: @user3628617: Which buffer are you referring to?

Comment: @user3628617 On how `printf()` (& Friends) works you might like to RTFM here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

Comment: i am referring to a buffer i use to receive data...it is not included in the code i posted...

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` returns an `int`, and applying the `%` operator on it also returns an `int` - you should save this result in an `int`, not a `char*`:

```
int num;
char *buffer;
```