# c++ Save Int with leading zeros to String, NOT displaying them

Tags: c++, string, int, leading-zero

I can format an `Int` to display a number with leading zeros, but I can't figure out how to save an `Int` with the zeros to a `string`.

Reason: Loading image files that end in `"..0001" "..0002" ... "..0059"` etc.

I have this, but it doesn't work:

```
int a;
for(int i = 1; i < imgArraySize + 1; i++)
{
    cout << setw(4) << setfill('0') << i << '\n';
    cin >> a;
    string aValue = to_string(a);

    imageNames.push_back(string("test_images" + aValue + ".jpg"));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a number to a string with specified length in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225362/convert-a-number-to-a-string-with-specified-length-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the same formatting with a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << a;
std::string str = ss.str();
std::cout << str;
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://ideone.com/rVDHuY)</kbd>

Comment: was about to post the same :/ just saw the question too late

Comment: Why `std::stringstream` instead of `std::ostringstream`?